# February 2013 Stack Overflow Moderator Election Town Hall Chat

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, election

In connection with the current [moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4), we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary. [Grace Note](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146126/grace-note) and I will be taking care of the scheduling and other logistics.

***The Spring 2013 Town Hall Chat took place Wednesday the 6th at 21:00:00Z UTC / 4:00 PM EST.***

***[read the transcript here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170715/february-2013-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest)***

---

Here are the details so far:

- We would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the primary phase. This means that we are looking around March 4-7. As soon as we coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, this post shall be edited with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: If it's the same as it's been done in the past, they'll send you a form on which you can specify your availability. It gives them a nice overview of how many people are available when, rather than just doing it all by hand/head.

Comment: I'm told that you do receive bonus points if you pick one of the days I work from home, and *double* bonus points if it's one day in particular. Just so everyone knows.

Comment: @TimStone Can I redeem these points for unicorn horns?

Comment: I can smell the mayhem already :)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Only if you collect enough.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII There is an international embargo on harvesting unicorn horns. In fact your medical problem is beyond fixing if you need to powder up unicorn horns to treat it. You can keep the whole unicorn as a pet though.

Comment: Should the chat room be switched or reset so we can get rid of last year's starred messages in the side bar?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yeah, I'm gonna clear them out.

Comment: @TimStone did we win?

Comment: @Flexo I'm willing to award bonus points and a half for picking Wednesday, and at a decent hour.