# February 2013 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat Digest

Tags: discussion, election

The following is a "digest" version of the [February 2013 Moderator Election Town Hall Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169754/february-2013-stack-overflow-moderator-election-town-hall-chat). The format, [as described on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests), is one *answer* to this question *for every question* asked in the Town Hall, containing all the candidate's answers to that question.

**To view the digest chronologically, please sort the answers by "oldest"**.

If you have questions or comments about this, **please do not answer this question** as the answers are designed to be used for the questions from the Town hall itself. Instead, please ask on [the parent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests) or in [the Town Hall Discussion Room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/352/town-hall-discussion).

If you see any corrections which need to be made to this digest, or if you were a candidate who was unable to attend the town hall and would like your answers included, please @GraceNote or @TimStone [in the chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/505/town-hall-chat) and let us know!

Comment: Thank you for compiling this! We know how difficult it was. Here, have my +1!

Comment: Where's the plus `int.MaxValue` button? Fantastic work Tim!

Comment: I'm being serious: Do you have a script for that?

Comment: +`(unsigned)-1`

Comment: @slhck Yeah, I have a script that pulls out all responses to whatever I select as a question and reverse-engineers the appropriate Markdown, which is part of the reason why explicit replies are encouraged. An older version just formatted individual posts, but that's *extremely* tedious. There's still some manual work involved, but I've managed to cut down the time pretty significantly from the early digests at least.

Comment: Question, wasn't the meeting took place on March? :P

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Yes, but the election itself technically started on February 25th.

Comment: This is great material to help me decide. But it will still be tough to pick only 3 candidates!

Answer (score 10):

### *[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113581#8113581):* **What drives you to *want* to be a moderator for Stack Overflow?**

---

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113613#8113613):**  I have learnt a lot from this community. While I may not have too many questions, I have found a lot of solutions by reading questions posted by other users. I want to give back to and help maintain this community.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113614#8113614):**  It drives me the willingness of doing something useful.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113616#8113616):**  Cleaning! More! Faster! (If you mean the reason behind *that*, I have no clue.)

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113624#8113624):**  I want to be a moderator to have all three chat mod powers (j/k). I want to be a mod, because I can make a real difference there. More than I can without the diamond.

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113626#8113626):**  That's an interesting one, Neal. I'd say that the critical reason is a striving for excellence on this site - both in my answers and others. I have made many edits to posts over the time that I have been here, and in fact most of them I come across while searching. I don't feel like it's simply enough to find the problems and flag them - I want to be able to handle these spammy situations on my own.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113631#8113631):**  I'm already a mod on another site and I find it very satisfying work.  It **is** work, though, so you have to really want to do it.  And if you enjoy it, SO is the big leagues.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113640#8113640):**  I hate seeing mis-spelled words in posts >.< But, seriously, I just want to give back to people who help me out.  Also, I sometimes see rudeness, and I want to keep this place happy.  Help new users understand what to do and not yell at them for doing it wrong.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113656#8113656):**  I just want to help out, and I believe mod powers can help me do a better job of that. StackOverflow is my number one resource for information, just from reading other people's questions and answers, so I want it to stay as high-quality as possible.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113663#8113663):**  I'm seeing a lot of activity on other sites (particularly Programmers) from users who have troubles on Stack Overflow. If I can see more information on both sites I can help them make the most of both sites rather than being simply blocked from all sides.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113672#8113672):**  Primarily the ability to do more for the site, as well as the idea of trust from the community to act on behalf of them.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113704#8113704):**  A lot of people encouraged me to nominate myself because of my work in the PHP tag. That is one of the major drivers for me. They believe in me.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113725#8113725):**  I want to be able to contribute to the site in a different way.  I would be able to benefit the site but not having the restrictions of *oops you hit your flagging limit for the day*. Without these in place, I think I could perform more cleanup.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113815#8113815):**  I like the site. I learn a lot from reading and participating in the site. I really like the Q&A model - it works in a way that changed programming problems online for me. I hope I can help further that vision by keeping a small patch orderly.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113886#8113886):**  As I said in my nomination blurb, I *don't* actively want to be an SO mod, at least by the conventional definition of "want." However, I love the SO community, I think SO has a great system, I know mods are important for keeping everything running smoothly and I believe I can do the job well.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115332#8115332):**  As I mentioned in a previous answer - binding close votes. *(whip crack)*

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116760#8116760):**  My passion to give back to the fantastic community that is Stack Overflow. I feel that I've learned an incredible amount, solely thanks to this community. I feel a sense of pride when performing tasks such as flagging/voting etc. as I'm playing my part in upholding the fantastic community. As a moderator, I feel I'd have even more tools to be able to give back so much more and help maintain the community.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124150#8124150):**  That's easy as pie; I *want* to be a moderator because I have gained so much knowledge from this site precisely because it is moderated in the way it is. I really only became active about two years ago; had I been here from the start, I'm not sure how impressed I would have been with it, compared to other sources. But I'm here *now*, and I love how the community has decided to moderate things, overall; and I want to help with that.

Answer (score 7):

### *[image: Shog9] [Shog9](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114679#8114679):* **[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964512/free-or-open-source-self-hosted-project-management-tools/15073000#15073000) pops up in the flag queue, with the flag "not an answer". What do you do?**

---

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114707#8114707):**  I wouldn't delete it. I would edit it, improving the quality, and send it back off into the wild. Which is what I'm doing now.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114708#8114708):**  Close the question as "non-constructive" and/or make the answer a comment.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114714#8114714):**  I would have to read the context. And then I see that it is basically a link pharm question -> Question should be closed/deleted --> answer was just because of the question.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114720#8114720):**  delete it

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114723#8114723):**  I do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15073000/revisions) first. Then I close the question.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114729#8114729):**  Make a comment to the user about the policy on self promotion, then delete it.  If he wants to clean it up and flag for undelete he can do that.  It's obvious from his profile that's a product he is associated with that he doesn't disclose in the "answer".  Looking deeper that is a questionable account and he may need a mod message.  All his answers are self-promotion.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114734#8114734):**  Dispute the flag, but comment to the person leaving the answer requesting that they elaborate further on the benefits of the solution they're proposing.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114748#8114748):**  Comment requesting elaboration after disputing flag. If no elaboration/improvement is made, delete and convert to comment.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114751#8114751):**  I decline it: The user is trying to answer, and it is not one of those "me too" answers, or answers asking a different question.

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114754#8114754):**  Convert it to a comment.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114756#8114756):**  Comment, wait (for several hours), and delete. Depending on the case, I might convert to comment.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114762#8114762):**  I believe I already voted to close that question when you brought it up in the Tavern. ;P

- **[image: Shog9] [Shog9](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114768#8114768):**  cheater

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114763#8114763):**  It would depend how old it was when it was flagged. If it's a new answer leave a comment asking the poster to leave more information. Possibly down-vote. If it was an older link only answer then I'd probably convert to a comment (if it pointed to a useful resource) or just delete.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114887#8114887):**  Of course the other thing to do is check the profile to see if there's any information that would indicate whether it was actually spam. In which case I'd flag it as such (which would immediately remove the answer) and see whether it was necessary to suspend or even destroy the user.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114812#8114812):**  I'd delete the entire question.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114882#8114882):**  Ugh. Leave it, since its low quality is mostly a function of the fact that it's a response to a bad question in the first place. I'd probably close the question if it wasn't already closed, though.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115257#8115257):**  take a look at other activity from the user and linking to the same URL. The post linked to looks like the whole question is problematic rather than just the individual post. Close on the question seems like a sensible place.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116328#8116328):**  Yep.. this is self promotion (the link is the same as listed in his profile under 'website'). If the user is spamming the site with links to the post then some serious action needs to be taken against that account. Otherwise delete the answer with a comment (perhaps with a link to the "attribution required" post) explaining why.

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8117130#8117130):**  Deem it as invalid, open the link, research the tool, edit the answer to provide a synopsis of what the tool offers. It's too easy to downvote and write something off, whereas a good mod in my opinion works to salvage the post.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124902#8124902):**  For *that specific answer*, I delete it on the basis of being Spam, because that person is connected with the product, has no disclosed that fact, hasn't provided any context or helpful information, and has made multiple posts just like it. *Also, though*, I vote to close the question, as it is a typical 'shopping question'. As a mod, that means the question would be closed immediately. Finally, I think the question needs to be deleted.

Comment: Shog9, @minitech: those links have disappeared - can you please post as JPEG next time, or archive some other way?

Answer (score 6):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/274402/grace-note) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113655#8113655):* **Of the other candidates, who is the one user you think would be most qualified for the position of moderator, and why?**

---

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113683#8113683):**  Andrew Barber - because he gets what Stack Overflow is about and seems to know what's required to keep the signal to noise ratio under control.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113697#8113697):**  Probably @ChrisF I have talked to him at length in the moderator chat room and he is very even-headed and no-nonsense about his job as a mod.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113702#8113702):**  Definitely Andrew Barber, even though I think he will push his radical haircut policies on all of us. He has an outstanding record of being useful with both flagging and on Meta, and he would be invaluable to the moderation team.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113706#8113706):**  @AndrewBarber --> heck of a lot of flags! Imagine what he can do with mod powers!

- **[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [remarked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113721#8113721):**  Flags !== to being a good mod. Yes, they are important, but I could easily get 1000 flags in a month by patrolling the /tools/flagged page.

  **[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113726#8113726):**  That is possible.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113707#8113707):**  I think that would be ChrisF. I read many of his answers on MSO, and he shows to know well what the moderator's task is.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113714#8113714):**  Andrew Barber. He's been a great example and done a lot of work to keep the site clean.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113736#8113736):**  I'm in favour of @minitech. We talk on Skype and frequently run into each other on the site as we patrol. Our names seem to show up often side-by-side on the "Closed by..." messages.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113748#8113748):**  I'd have to say @Gordon, although Andrew Barber is also high on my list.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113790#8113790):**  Definitely Andrew Barber, I think he has the skills needed for the job

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113835#8113835):**  Kolink because he seems like a cool guy, and I see his answers when I go post an answer and he's usually right :)

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113838#8113838):**  @animuson. My most important criterion is number of edits, and his really show that he's dedicated to improving it all :)

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113882#8113882):**  I havent seen much of the other moderators work, but from their nomination texts and stats I'd say Andrew Barber. He seems really dedicated and doing even more moderation than me already. My favorite is not on the list on the though (that would be Pekka)

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113982#8113982):**  Andrew Barber. As I said in response to an earlier question, I think flagging is huge for a mod, and he's got the best flag history of any candidate, hands-down. In fact, I'll repeat here the promise I made under his nomination blurb: even though I decided to run, my first vote is going to him.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114101#8114101):**  Andrew Barber and animuson. I've seen them around a lot and always felt like their actions were correct.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115552#8115552):**  The most qualified candidates are those who have already qualified to be moderators on other SE sites. From them I'd say, partly attributed to my interactions with him on meta, @ChrisF is a solid choice and would make a great moderator.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124220#8124220):**  It's difficult to pick one. I so much wanted to list three here. But since you are making me pick one, I would pick @animuson. I think the 'raw data' available certainly more than qualifies him, but more than that, I have seen his Meta participation, and it makes me feel like his feelings about the site follow that of the community - and myself.

Answer (score 5):

### *[image: Lamak] [Lamak](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/519216/lamak) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113333#8113333):* **I know from posts and meta and chat some of you, but not all names are familiar to me. Why should I trust the moderation of this site to you?**

---

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113375#8113375):**  Partly because I'm already trusted on three other sites. I know what moderation is all about and it won't come as a shock to me (hopefully).

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113384#8113384):**  I haven't banned you on DBA yet!  But seriously, we don't need anything revolutionary on SO, we need consistent forward movement and maintenance.  I know I can provide that.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113385#8113385):**  You should look at the facts before voting. Raising a bunch of flags is nice, but anyone with 10k and enough dedication can do that. I actively review, edit, close, delete and vote, in order to moderate the site. I don't leave jobs for moderators if I can do it myself.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113395#8113395):**  I have already demonstrated my dedication to keeping the site clean with over 1400 helpful flags, and similar amount of reviews in other review queues, along with lots of edits and closing.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113412#8113412):**  I think I have already proven my commitment to the site through my editing, flagging of answers. I know I would be a good mod on SO.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113416#8113416):**  I'm lead administrator on the sites I've made, and my job there is pretty much the same as a diamond-mod here: to perform certain administrative tasks and handle anything regular users with mod priviledges can't. My sites are now four years old and doing well, so I like to think I do a good job. Of course, I'm just some guy on the internet to you, so it's really your call.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113425#8113425):**  Because I'm awesome!  No, but seriously, because I am very diligent in my work and take myself seriously and because I am nice to new users.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113443#8113443):**  My only answer to that is the usual claims that everyone makes; I'm fair, I'm patient, I can deal with random Internet people yelling at me, I know how the site works. I encourage you to look at my activity history -- and the other candidates' -- to see if you agree with my -- and their -- past actions.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113447#8113447):**  In all the time I've been a user I don't think I've done anything that would cause you not to trust me. My history is clean. The only contact I've had with team@ was initiated by me because the character limit on the flag box was too short for a specific problem.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113466#8113466):**  you should trust if you share my/our vision of a searchable quality resort of Q&As on the web

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113540#8113540):**  History. If you haven't noticed anything particularly trustworthy in passing, I suppose it would just be a matter of looking back at what's available. Previous actions are probably the most important thing I could do to sway anyone, personally.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114495#8114495):**  I'm a [pretty friendly guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix?tab=activity) who's [active on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/172936/lix) and keen on assisting as much as I can to the maintenance of the site.

Comment: Oops! I totally missed this question! Wouldn't be fair to answer it now, though.

Answer (score 4):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/274402/grace-note) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113204#8113204):* **In your opinion, what do moderators do?**

---

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113210#8113210):**  Maintain some form of sanity ;)

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113212#8113212):**  Clean up the spillage in aisle 5

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113216#8113216):**  Moderators can be anywhere from glorified garbagemen to principals of the school.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113215#8113215):**  Handle exceptional situations that the usual community moderation system can't.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113223#8113223):** As well as reviewing the flags that are raised as part of the usual system, of course.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113218#8113218):**  They are the exception handlers that keep the trashcan clean.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113219#8113219):**  Moderators lead the community. Plain and simple. It's more about garbage disposal, it's about giving people an image to look at and mimic.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113220#8113220):**  They make sure this site is clean and friendly.  We make sure everyone uses this site the way it should be so that everyone is happy! :)

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113224#8113224):**  Moderators work to maintain and lead the community.

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113225#8113225):**  An excellent question, Anna. I think that the core of what moderators do has to do with the custom flags around the site, and overall maintenance.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113227#8113227):**  *As little as possible* if we take the Theory of Moderation. In a nutshell I'd say keep StackOverflow a place everyone can enjoy and find quality answers on.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113228#8113228):**  Moderators keep the site clean and act as examples of good community members.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113232#8113232):**  My view: handle the stuff that the community can't. "Can't" could mean lack of traffic but got flagged still, it could mean disputed and resolving disputes and it could mean privileged actions that no amount of rep confers to non-mods.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113233#8113233):**  Moderators remove spam and help angry people. (And clean up stuff in a vote.) (Yeah, I went non-metaphorical for once!)

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113236#8113236):**  The role of moderators is to do the little maintenance tasks the community can't handle or doesn't want to handle.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113237#8113237):**  As little as possible, but they do it well. For the most part, flagging, deleting, closing etc. is handled really well by high-reputation users. Mod should only need to get involved if there is a disagreement, such as disputed flags, although that doesn't mean they shouldn't take part in the normal voting system too - just so long as it's done right.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113240#8113240):**  Depends on the site.  On smaller sites they do a more diverse set of tasks than on larger ones like SO.  SO is unique in that there are a lot more users with mod privileges than on most of the rest of the network.  On DBA I do a lot of hand holding and community building.  On SO I plan to focus mainly on the flag queue and more specific admin tasks like migration/deletions.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113280#8113280):**  Ultimately, they speak for the community - primarily through flags, but also but providing feedback and guidance.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113343#8113343):**  Deal with situations beyond the control of the community.

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116404#8116404):**  Moderators are "human exception handlers". They play a fundamental part in the large task that is regulating and maintaining the community, with the help from many StackOverflow users be it from the flagging system, editing, voting etc. Without them, the majority of the content on this site wouldn't be anywhere near the level of quality that it is at the moment, but things can only get better! If I was voted, I'd love to strive to make that even better.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8123816#8123816):**  Moderators handle those things that the community and automated systems can't (very well) handle themselves; things that are so exceptional that they need a faster and perhaps 'stronger' response than the community can provide, or a more nuanced response than automated systems can provide.

Answer (score 4):

### *[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113654#8113654):* **When do you feel that closed questions should and should not be deleted?**

---

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113665#8113665):**  Are they useful closed, even in the slightest? If yes, keep.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113671#8113671):**  They should be deleted when they are very bad examples of questions to ask.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113674#8113674):**  You mean closed, and still kept?  I think only really bad posts, like "can I have teh code plz" should be closed.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113677#8113677):**  If the question has any potential redemption value, I'd leave it for a while at least.  If it's obviously a throw-away question there's no need to keep it.  But you do need to give the OP a chance to clean it up.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113680#8113680):**  When a question is useful and/or it has value to the community --> many views and upvotes etc.

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113682#8113682):**  Well, brad, questions should be left open if they have a significant number of answers that could potentially be useful to future visitors - regardless of whether the question is on-topic, constructive, or whatever. Questions should only be deleted if they are too localized & have no answers, or are spam.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113686#8113686):**  Blatantly offtopic/spam/super low quality should be deleted. Slightly to properly useful questions should be kept

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113687#8113687):** If a closed question is of absolutely of no use - delete it - otherwise, I consider it for re-opening

- **[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [remarked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113698#8113698):**  The real question here is where do you draw that line, I believe.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113690#8113690):**  Easy, a closed question should not be deleted if it has *any* value. Is it salvageable using edits? Is the OP likely to expand on it? Does it have good answers? No need to delete it then. Also, I tend to avoid deleting a post in the first 24 hours (unless, of course, it is spam).

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113701#8113701):**  Duplicate questions should be kept, especially now that they are specifically labelled as dupes rather then just "closed". By having multiple questions with different titles but the same purpose, they can help future users search for what they need. On the other hand, questions that are not constructive would probably be the biggest candidates for deletion, but only if they don't seem salvageable with a suitable edit.

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113705#8113705):**  I'm probably rare in being in favor of deleting (or, possibly, merging) most of the duplicates, because they make Google searches frustrating; I shouldn't need to follow a chain of duplicate posts to find a good answer.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113766#8113766):**  I think that questions should be closed and deleted if it was closed with no answers to it.  If the question is closed but has a great answer, then it shouldn't be deleted.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113777#8113777):**  Duplicates shouldn't be deleted. They're useful to get hits from alternate search terms. Otherwise if the question is completely unsalvageable then it should probably be deleted sooner rather than later. However, there should be ample opportunity for it to be improved and reopened if it can.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113781#8113781):**  That's a tough one. In general, I am in favor of deleting what was closed. But I decide on a case by case basis. We have some Q&A that are closed but provide very nice answers with good information. These should be kept. By like I said: case by case.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113970#8113970):**  Closure is only temporary. So is deletion but it makes things much harder for users to find and fix. I dislike quick 20k deletion of bad questions before the OP even has a chance to see why it was closed. Nobody wins from that because the OP goes away wondering if it ever got posted at all (was it just lost by a bug?) and often just reposts the same bad question again. Closure is a good stepping stone that sends a clear message ("this isn't fit for purpose, fix it or lose it").

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114019#8114019):** I have no qualms with a question being closed quickly after it was asked though - the OP had all the time in the world up until they hit the post button to get it into a good state.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115449#8115449):**  This is exactly why the site needs moderators. That question is impossible to answer without having a specific post to reference. delete/undelete wars ensue and someone needs to step in and lock it down.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115946#8115946):**  Would it be too glib to just say I'd follow the current guidelines? I'd reserve deletion for questions that are *blatantly* off-topic, unanswerable or offensive, excluding historically locked posts. Closing is for stuff that just doesn't meet standards.

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116786#8116786):**  If a closed question still provides useful knowledge/information, or contains solutions that are likely to be searched for, then the question should remain un-deleted to help bring in further traffic from people encountering the same issue. If however the question is of no use to anybody, then it is best that it is deleted.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124182#8124182):**  I feel that closed questions should be deleted when their visibility does not serve any worthwhile purpose. Well-worded duplicates serve as signposts, for example, and should remain. Beyond that, I feel *most* closed posts which don't get reopened should be deleted; if it remains closed, it's because the community feels it lacks the quality to be here in the first place. Why should it, then, remain visible? There are exceptions, like those the community has decided are 'Historical'.

Answer (score 4):

### *[image: Shog9] [Shog9](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113740#8113740):* **Sooner or later, you'll do something as part of your normal moderator duties that offends someone, and he'll jump on MSO cursing your name and demanding vengeance.  How will you respond to this?**

---

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113768#8113768):**  I would try to let the other moderators handle it at the start and then, when I can, write a **well thought** out response that will try not to slight the user.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113769#8113769):**  I've had an example of such a case but it got deleted. Answer constructively, don't feed the trolls. Provide evidence of you being right, and apologize if you were wrong.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113770#8113770):**  I will post an answer to his question and explain the reasons for which I took whatever action offended him. If it is found that I was wrong, I will reverse the action, apologise and learn from my mistake.

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113779#8113779):**  Tell him he's a liar! No, not really.  I would be calm, and try to explain the situation from an impartial point of view. The most important thing here is to not loose your 'cool'. And not try to silence a user, but let them vent towards me, while not hurting the site.

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113782#8113782):**  I'll attempt to address their concerns rationally, keeping in mind that most people doing that just want to vent and aren't going to be persuaded by rationality.

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113789#8113789):** I spend my life living with someone that believe's she's always wronged because the hours I work etc.. etc... I think I can live with some criticism

- **[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [remarked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113808#8113808):**  The point isn't dealing with the criticism here - it's about dealing with the accusation more than anything, IMO.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113791#8113791):**  I'll explain myself, casually, and try to keep my cool.  If he can give me a valid reason why he's right and I'm not, then we'll talk.  If he's just angry, I may just ignore it and let the community tell him what's up.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113792#8113792):**  Get someone on the SE dev team to attribute the posts to casperOne so nobody is surprised :)  Honestly, I have no problem defending my actions to a user.  If I WAS wrong, I also have no problem admitting that.  We aren't doing open heart surgery hear, this is programming questions on the innertubes.  Nothing is life-and-death and excited users may need to be reminded of that once in a while.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113798#8113798):**  I would laugh my backside off. Heck, I already have one blog dedicated to my assorted "screwups" (entirely hearsay, the creator doesn't even use my site), and it is a perpetual source of entertainment.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113833#8113833):**  I'd first see if it was anything I could fix myself straight away, if not then I'd leave it for another moderator to review my actions and decide what they thought was the right action. Second guessing yourself will lead you to make more bad decisions down the line.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113850#8113850):**  I will let other moderators answer.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113855#8113855):**  Letting other users and moderators deal with the situation is usually a better way to put out any flames than directly confronting the user. I would generally keep track of the topic and post specific responses in order to clear things up that users are confused about, but try and avoid interacting too much.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113912#8113912):**  I would explain the reason for any action that I took while keeping my cool.  I can fully acknowledge when I have made a mistake and have no issue admitting my faults.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113918#8113918):**  Close it, assuming that rantiness implies unconstructiveness~!

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114066#8114066):**  Try to talk to the person and settle things. Only reasonable thing to do. If s/he cannot be reasoned with, defer him to someone else.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114361#8114361):**  If I'm doing it right then there's a rational, calmly expressed justification for every action. My instinct would be to post that, but not get drawn into a mud bath. If there's a broader issue at stake then I'm all for drawing that out from the specific incident. If a reasoned response doesn't work I hope the other moderators would help deal with the situation.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115741#8115741):**  There will always be super-active users on meta who I trust will dull the blow :P I would respond in the same way as any interaction on the site. Friendly but stern (when necessary). I won't let it turn into a cussing match, but I'll be very willing to explain the rational behind whatever action the user found offensive, and if needed, I wouldn't have a problem reversing the action should I be satisfied that a mistake was made.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115802#8115802):**  Actually, if history is any guide, I won't have to do anything. When anti-mod polemics show up on MSO, other users typically jump in pretty quickly. If I really did screw up big time, I'd just explain what happened calmly and professionally, promise to resolve the issue and then get right to work with fellow mods to fix it and make sure I didn't repeat the mistake.

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116832#8116832):**  Diplomatically, I'll respond by ensuring that the user knows that I did it purely on what I thought was best for the community, not for any other personal agenda or otherwise.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124317#8124317):**  I'll deal with Meta complaints about my actions as Mod in close to the same way I've dealt with it as the 'flagging user', though there is a major difference: I get to choose whether to 'out' myself as the flagging user, but I won't have that choice as a mod. Simple answer: explain why I made that decision, and be open to being wrong. And always remember that every moderator action needs to be defensible, in the first place, before I even do it.

Answer (score 4):

### *[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113897#8113897):* **How relevant do you think the *age* factor for moderators are? We have some pretty young candidates this year. Do you think it'll affect their moderation?**

---

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113902#8113902):**  step back - if it's a topic I'm "good in", then I'd normally cast a vote or submit an edit, otherwise... the community around us has to be more informed and respect their opinion

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113920#8113920):**  "with age comes knowledge" is the old saying... I do **not** think it applies in this context.

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113953#8113953):**  I'm sure there are mature teenagers. I can't say that when I was a teen I knew anyone I'd trust as a moderator. I know what I was like in my teens and early 20s and I wouldn't trust that version of myself.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113955#8113955):**  I think experience in life is helpful in making thoughtful decisions, generally speaking.  I don't think that precludes any of the younger candidates from being qualified, but there's a reason we don't let kids drive or vote - decision making is biologically impaired until a certain age.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113967#8113967):**  Not at all! (Averages are meaningless.)

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113968#8113968):**  Age has nothing to do with how good a moderator you are. Some of the better ones are still teenagers. However on a personal note I'd say that if you think age is a factor, vote for me :)

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113978#8113978):** I don't think I'm exactly qualified to answer that (as I'm 16), but I'll try:    The real reason that people are concerned is about maturity, right? Personally, I think that maturity is shown by your experience on the site, and the quality of the posts/flags you make.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114004#8114004):**  It surely affect the way they moderate, but that doesn't necessarily mean in a bad way. Probably they have a different *point of view* that allows them to see things differently.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114006#8114006):**  Age is just a number. There are plenty of young people out there that are plenty mature to handle a responsibility such as this. Focus on whether they are a good candidate should entirely be placed on their activity and how they've been interacting with the site.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114011#8114011):**  I don't think the user's age is that much of a big deal, but I do believe that an account's age (ie. how long ago they joined and how active they have been in that time) does matter. After all, a 50-year-old who just got enough to nominate themselves wouldn't be as much use as a 17-year-old with 5 years on SO.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114013#8114013):**  I'm one of the young candidates here. I believe my age will not be a problem. In 7 years of working with code and people related to it, my age has **never** been a problem.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114230#8114230):**  I think there are plenty of teenagers who have proven that they could be good moderators. So I don't think age plays a factor.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114268#8114268):**  The only reason people talk about age is that it's an approximation for maturity. But we have a better metric than that: we can actually look through individual candidates' post, revision and comment histories and see whether they're mature or not. So it's essentially pointless to consider age as a factor.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114337#8114337):**  in general, I'd favor someone older over a teenager because of the general life experience they will have. But that doesn't mean that the younger candidates are ill-suited. If the have the dedication and the skill, let them have a diamond.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114638#8114638):**  On the internet physical age is less obvious. There are some middle aged adults who act like spoilt teenagers and there are some teenagers who act 30+. For all we know someone who hasn't declared their age could be the youngest one here.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115905#8115905):**  I think the age factor is just as irrelevant as the reputation factor.

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116894#8116894):**  Age is but a number. Maturity doesn't correlate with age, which is incredibly evident when you see how young and how mature some of the users on StackOverflow are.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124433#8124433):**  I don't feel age should be an issue in choosing moderators, beyond them being of appropriate age to be on the site in the first place (13+). Beyond that, I don't care about their age. I want to know if they have a level head; if they know the difference between what *they* want and what the *community* wants, if they are able to take criticism, if they are patient, etc.

Answer (score 3):

### *[image: NullUserException] [NullUserException](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113328#8113328):* **How do you think moderating will affect your participation as far as asking and answering questions go? ie: Do you think you'll have enough time for both, or are you willing to forgo "normal" participation in order to moderate?**

---

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113338#8113338):**  I believe I will have enough time for both.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113339#8113339):**  I'm both willing to forgo normal participation in order to moderate and in the belief that I won't need to often. After all, there's a rep cap :( Anyways, I found time to go through two review queues every morning.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113340#8113340):**  I already spend too much time here as it is, so I should have enough time to do both.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113342#8113342):**  I will have the time to do both.

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113345#8113345):**  Right now, I don't focus on answering questions, and nor do I  ask them frequently. I'll still pitch in in situations where I feel that I can add something that others can't, but I wouldn't expect anything more than what I contribute now

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113347#8113347):**  As I [answered @Shog9](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113305#8113305), I *do not* think I would be answering as much as I used to because I will have a lot more on my plate.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113348#8113348):**  I don't see a contradiction between both. We already have moderators both answering and moderating (also, isn't that what we already do?)

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113349#8113349):**  With the amount of time I spend on SO, there's time for both participating and moderating.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113352#8113352):**  If my experience on the other sites is anything to go by I'll be answering a lot fewer questions than I do now. But that's not a bad thing.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113354#8113354):**  I currently do both. I answer questions and flag/edit posts throughout the day. I don't expect my behavior to change.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113364#8113364):**  I think my ability to contribute as a mod far outweighs my ability to contribute knowledge in my main area of SQL.  There are a lot smarter people than me answering questions, but they don't all have the stomach or patience for moderation.  I know I already have those and I enjoy it.

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113367#8113367):**  I'm already answering a lot less than I used to, concentrating on moderation (it helps to be mostly expert in Python where most questions have good answers 10 seconds after they're posted.)

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113372#8113372):**  my "normal" participation has shifted away from answering the questions that tend to attract many answers quickly towards unanswered harder, older questions. I see that trend continuing.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113374#8113374):**  I will likely not answer more than I do today, which is already very little. Most questions coming up nowadays are dupes anyway.

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113377#8113377):** As I said in my nomination - my focus is more towards community building now anyway, so wouldn't bother for a moment - in terms of time - I'm normally here about 10 hours a day anyway

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113380#8113380):**  I'm already not much of an answerer, as I stated in my nomination blurb, so no big loss there. I really only ask when I've exhausted all other research options, and I don't expect that to change; that's coming out of a different "pool" of time than moderation time would be.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113391#8113391):**  As stated in my nomination post, I don't tend to participate much in the normal sense anyways. I do browse questions occasionally looking for things to answer, but I'm much more content with helping out.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114225#8114225):**  I'm sure my "normal" participation will decrease a little bit but I doubt moderating would prevent it altogether.

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116566#8116566):**  As mentioned in my original nomination, I have recently seen question answering taking more of a back seat more and more and this is the direction that I'd like to head in. My SO day used to be answer, answer, answer. Now it's review flags, review review queues, vote questions/answers that I like, then answer if I have time left (I usually do :). Answering is now last on my list, the moderator-esque duties take full priority, which they would do so even more if I was a Moderator.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8123946#8123946):**  I expect that moderating will have some effect on my asking/answering, and that is OK by me. However, I already spend a significant amount of time doing 10k-related moderating tasks, and then answering things also as I come across them. I can see still doing that as I flip through the home page listing of questions.

Answer (score 3):

### *[image: NullUserException] [NullUserException](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113712#8113712):* **As a regular user, you cast votes to close and delete posts. But these votes only take effect when more users agree with you. How will binding close/delete votes affect your decision making?**

---

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113727#8113727):**  Not at all. I don't vote to close or delete unless I'm sure.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113734#8113734):**  I will comment first and explain why the post is bad, so the user can fix it before I cast my "uber-vote".

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113743#8113743):**  None at all.  If I think it needs to be closed then I feel as strongly about it as a mod as I do as a regular user.  I don't vote on things unless I am sure either as a mod or a voter.

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113745#8113745):** Mods are basically garbage collectors

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113754#8113754):**  As I said earlier, I'd be less strict with close votes (this isn't because I'm less sure of them, but rather because moderator closing feels horribleish sometimes), but everything else would be the same.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113755#8113755):**  No difference. I don't cast my vote unless I am sure that there is no other option. In other cases, I prefer to leave a comment first and try to salvage the post.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113775#8113775):**  I don't think a mod should cast the first vote, unless it's a really obvious case. I believe it'd be better for a mod to respond to existing votes to make a binding decision rather than jump the gun.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113813#8113813):**  It will not affect my decision, except that as moderator I vote to close those questions that are blatantly off-topic, not a real question, not constructive, or too localized. In any case, I will not vote to close those questions that I don't think deserve to be closed. The fact other users already voted doesn't influence my decision.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113828#8113828):**  None at all. If it needs to be closed then it should be closed.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113997#8113997):**  Unless it's a clear candidate for closing, I will wait until there is four votes before throwing in my vote.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114138#8114138):**  I will be a bit more restrained. Even well-meaning binding votes can come off as "I'm the big powerful mod screwing over the little guy," especially to new users. But I'll still go through the same process of deciding whether something is close- or delete-worthy.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114143#8114143):**  I'm not sure if I've already answered this - but if stuff needs closing/deleting it needs closing/deleting. My actions can always be reversed.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114232#8114232):**  I expect that this would push me away from the borderline posts and away from the higher volume tags where the community tends to be much better at self-policing.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114594#8114594):**  I may be more careful when deleting things since posts deleted by a moderator can only be undeleted by a moderator, but closing is easily reversible by the community so I can't say my close-voting behavior will change to drastically.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115626#8115626):**  Not at all (I hope). Many times I feel myself wanting to close a question with a binding vote. I'd want to leave a comment when casting a binding vote but this isn't always possible.

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116804#8116804):**  The same with flagging, I'll spend more time weighing up the evidence before making a decision as the decision is final, so I think I should go out of my way to ensure that it is the right decision.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124295#8124295):**  I think having that extra-powered Moderator vote to close is definitely a major ability, and I would exercise it very carefully. Right now, an 'incorrect' close vote is simply wasted (which is still a concern of mine, since I often use up all of my votes), but the more heavily my vote would count, the more extra-certain I would have to be.

Answer (score 3):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/274402/grace-note) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114322#8114322):* **Is there anything in becoming a moderator that makes you uneasy or nervous?**

---

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114342#8114342):**  Nope, not at all.  I'm comfortable with all the tools and processes already.

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114343#8114343):**  Yes, the distinct lack of unicorns in my name.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114346#8114346):**  I hope people aren't intimidated by me when I ask or answer a question. :P

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114350#8114350):**  There is nothing about being moderator that makes me nervous.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114358#8114358):**  I'm feeling uneasy and nervous that I'm probably own't be elected this time round, but no. I'm looking forward for moderatorship.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114364#8114364):**  As a moderator one would be much much more in the public eye and scrutinized for everything he or she does (oh wait... I think I am already in that category...)

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114374#8114374):**  I'm kind of nervous about offending people. It happens almost no matter what when you do moderatey things :/

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114376#8114376):**  I've used the tools for a while now, so no.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114388#8114388):**  I'm usually confident in taking action, and in my experience if a leader can't show confidence then they're no leader.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114399#8114399):**  Only the risk that I neglect the other sites I moderate.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114426#8114426):**  Just the three-week process it takes to become one.

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114428#8114428):**  it won't change

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114387#8114387):** I could do the same thing I'm doing with more privilege - so errr...

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114465#8114465):**  Nope if I felt that way I would not have nominated myself. :)

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114530#8114530):**  not at all. I am looking forward to join the team.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114899#8114899):**  Finding my feet without being a burden on the existing moderators will be tricky, but I'm confident it's something I can adapt to.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115868#8115868):**  Sure I'm nervous. I don't ever want to make the wrong call, but I'm human, and at some point I'm going to screw up. Heck, I already feel bad about it. I also worry that I won't live up to the standard of the current mods. But I think I have the healthy kind of nervousness, the kind that will keep me sharp, not the crippling kind that will prevent me from doing the job.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116077#8116077):**  Being in the spotlight is always a little bit nerve racking but all in all I'm very excited by the possibility!

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8117015#8117015):**  I wouldn't say so, it's nothing that's not to be expected. I know what I'm signing myself up to and I'm so committed to do so that I have no unease or nervousness :)

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124713#8124713):**  I think the thing that makes me most uneasy is that I would like to *never* make a mistake as a moderator - but I know I will. I always try to take criticism constructively, but the perfectionist inside of me dies a little bit every time I "fail" in some way.

Answer (score 3):

### *[image: swasheck] [swasheck](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/251174/swasheck) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115137#8115137):* **To those who said they'd moderate while on the job. What do you believe your boss would say if they discovered this level of involvement?**

---

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115149#8115149):**  I am my boss. `Kolink.boss === Kolink`

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115152#8115152):**  Umm... Can I plead the 5th ammendment?

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115155#8115155):**  I'm sure they'd be happy.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115162#8115162):**  I don't have a boss.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115174#8115174):**  I'm a freelancer and can use my time as I see fit :)

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115177#8115177):**  I won't moderate on the job. (Sadly, no internet computer access from there *yet*). But when I would, only on free-time and not during productive time. I like to have a separation between the two.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115180#8115180):**  5th

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115215#8115215):**  I hope they would be OK with it.  If not I'll work for SE!

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115218#8115218):**  Well most of my Stack Exchange activity is first thing in the morning or at lunchtime (with the odd 5 minutes here and there during the day) so it doesn't affect my work anyway.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115248#8115248):**  I won't tell him.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115266#8115266):**  Probably nothing. I'd only be popping in while a build was running or during lunch, not spending the entire afternoon clearing flags. (Sorry, current mods.)

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8117185#8117185):**  My boss and all of my coworkers voted for me, so they fully support my standing (My boss is actually an active user on StackOverflow too :))

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: Anna Lear] [Anna Lear](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/105971/anna-lear) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113399#8113399):* **If you are elected, a diamond will be attached to everything you do and everything you've ever done. How do you anticipate dealing with that? Will it affect the way you're making decisions, and if so how?**

---

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113422#8113422):**  no my intent wouldn't change

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113452#8113452):**  just because I had a "binding vote" wouldn't change my attitude as to bad posts and those salvageable via an edit

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113428#8113428):**  I am already a moderator, and I am used to that. It doesn't change the comments I leave (if not in the case I leave them for moderating posts); it doesn't change the answer I give.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113429#8113429):**  Nope, this won't change how I operate.  I may have to edit some of my comments and such from 3 years back but otherwise I'll operate the same.

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113430#8113430):**  No, I don't think so. It makes little difference, as it's just a visual thing. My mindset has always been that of one who is interested in the long-term. I wouldn't ruin my reputation as a person due to a little icon.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113433#8113433):**  As mentioned in my last answer, everything I do on the sites I own is labelled with an `@` sign and a purple name. I'm used to the effect of being highlighted wherever I go ;)

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113442#8113442):**  I don't think I'll change.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113445#8113445):**  That my goal! It will affect the way I make decisions only in the aspect that my vote is binding. I won't close questions (Even if I know they are technically unanswerable) unless 4 votes have already accumulated. (Obviously, for questions that *needs* to be closed, I won't hesitate).

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113449#8113449):**  I think I will look at flags in a different light and weigh my decisions based on what I learned in the past. But all in all I do not think things will change *that* much.

- **[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113459#8113459):**  I'm interested in that. How, specifically will you look at them 'differently'?

  **[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113475#8113475):**  well by close/delete votes are **much** more binding as a moderator and I have to take that into consideration

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113454#8113454):**  This will not change how I operate.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113524#8113524):**  To clarify my behavior won't change because I already an invested in improving the quality of the site.  I go through old posts for editing or flagging, I would continue this same process as a mod just with fewer steps.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113463#8113463):**  It will affect the way I make decisions in regards to closing — I'd be less strict on that. Apart from that, not at all.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113464#8113464):**  As long as others don't get intimidated by me, my attitude will stay the same.  I'm usually very helpful and I will continue to be.  I don't yell, I explain myself :)

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113496#8113496):**  It will make me slightly more hesitant to cast close and delete votes, simply because they are binding. However, if stuff needs closing or deleting I will cast a vote even if I'm the only one. As I said earlier there's stuff that needs handling more quickly that the community can manage.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113503#8113503):**  If I had to predict, I'd say yes. I've always tried to view things from a moderator's perspective, but you can never quite get the correct mindset until it actually happens.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113593#8113593):**  I will likely be more cautious with decisions. Right now, I am quite stern and dedicated when it comes to pruning dupes and low quality stuff.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113620#8113620):**  For the most part I'm totally happy with that. I think it will make me less likely to act on border line cases I see through general browsing rather than from the flag queue - gauging the feeling of the rest of the community by being 1 vote out of many won't be an option any more.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113627#8113627):**  I'm happy to have a diamond attached to any of my past actions. It's a cliche, but I like to think I hold myself to a high standard whether I'm an official authority figure or not. Going forward, I might be a bit less likely to take actions that the community could do on its own, just because a binding vote is inherently different than a "regular" one.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114777#8114777):**  I'd like to think that it wouldn't affect my decisions at all. I intend to remain consistent with my methodologies.

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116656#8116656):**  I think I'd take extra care when speaking around the community (I do already) because it's the extra responsibility, "wearing" that diamond means that I'd be a representative of the SO team and that's a great reputation I'd strive to uphold/maybe even increase!? In terms of flagging, I think I'll take extra care when reviewing items and looking at things in more detail, as I'll be the final say in the matter.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124041#8124041):**  Having a diamond after my name will definitely make me think twice (thrice?) about everything I say and do, because I am no longer representing *just* myself. I already consider it important to represent myself well, but there are things that are OK for "me" which are possibly not OK for me *as* a Stack Overflow moderator. I plead the fifth on what those things might be...

Comment: What kind of "Hot Air" question is that?

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113460#8113460):* **Which do you view as more important for a candidate, raising flags, meta participation, or close/delete activity? And why?**

---

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113500#8113500):**  Meta. Raising flags means absolutely nothing other than they can patrol the review queues or /tools/flags, and close & delete means nothing towards how they can improve questions. Edits & meta are the most important things.

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113506#8113506):**  Close/Delete; most of the flagging reasons are for stuff a 10K user can do without flagging, and while *reading* meta is very important, I don't see that being quick to pounce on questions with answers is all that important a criteria.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113507#8113507):**  flags and close/delete because even if a user is **not** on meta, it does not mean they do not know how the system works.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113508#8113508):**  Close/delete activity.  This shows that we know what belongs here and what doesn't.  Flags usually represent very bad posts, which I hope to not see too often (but they do happen).

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113512#8113512):**  All of the above. A moderator shouldn't specialise in just one aspect of the site, lest other parts be left abandoned. A good mod should be well-rounded.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113513#8113513):**  I would say raising flags, and meta participation; between them, meta participation is more important, IMO.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113514#8113514):**  Quality edits and meta participation. Casting close votes and raising flags is done by literally thousands of other users. The candidates should focus on working on things which fewer people are working on.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113525#8113525):**  I don't think any are particularly indicative of future performance as a mod.  Close/deletes are probably closest to what you actually do as a moderator.  Raising flags for most scenarios becomes redundant when you can cast votes.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113546#8113546):**  All three, though these activities should be secondary to answering questions, editing posts and generally guiding users to the best way to use Stack Overflow.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113591#8113591):**  I can't say that any one is more important than the other. While flagging and close/delete history reflect on your views more personally, meta participation also plays a key role in analyzing situations and explaining why things occurred (since we all know replying to flags is a bit difficult).

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113612#8113612):**  I look at all three activities but I think that contributing to the community by answering questions is very important.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113637#8113637):**  I consider all duties that the regulars cannot moderate as most important. So, flag handling first and then closing/deleting.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113669#8113669):**  I think they're all important. I don't think coming in "cold" in any of those aspects would be a good thing. If I had to single one out I'd go with meta participation since it reflects activity from the other categories as well as the broader community.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113700#8113700):**  Certainly all three are important, but I'd say raising flags is the most important of the three. That's because mods are the ones who end up handling the flags, so they need to have really deep understanding of not only how the mechanics of flagging work but also what sort of things are flaggable and the philosophy behind the system. Meta, closing and deleting are a bit more open to the community.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114441#8114441):**  Neither of those: edits. In my opinion, it's the best gauge of willingness to improve stuff.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115039#8115039):**  In order of importance -

1. **Helpful flags** (the ability to recognize problems with a post/user. Close votes also fall into this category).
2. **Meta Participation** (the pretty much means reading through the endless hidden FAQ posts that every and all meta posts get closed as duplicates of. A healthy knowledge of "how the site works").
3. **Delete activity** (the ability to recognize junk).

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116679#8116679):**  I think that a good balance of all of those makes a well rounded Moderator. It's pointless focusing all of your effort in one of those areas, it's all of those combined that help maintain the community.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124088#8124088):**  As a candidate, I feel they are all important. Although much has been made of my helpful flag count, I feel that my Meta participation possibly gives a better idea of what I'm really about. For flagging and voting, I think I more feel like there is a level that makes you 'acceptable', and it has meaning otherwise, but ultimately, that's just a number; what can you tell from just a number? For instance - what if my 9200+ Helpful Flags also included 5000 *Not* helpful flags?

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: swasheck] [swasheck](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/251174/swasheck) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113515#8113515):* **How would you encourage notable *experts* who frequent the site but are frustrated by what appears to be laziness by other high-rep users?**

---

- **[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [asked for clarification](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113522#8113522):**  Can you expand on that?

  **[image: swasheck] [swasheck](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/251174/swasheck) [clarified](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113601#8113601):**  Essentially it's a weight-pulling question. if an expert sees another high-rep user not "pulling their weight." how do you encourage the disenchanted expert?

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113534#8113534):**  I'm not sure how you can. If someone is discouraged by the lack of quality on questions or answers, then they should attempt to make a difference themselves.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113552#8113552):**  Show them good questions, where even low-rep users give good answers to good questions.  High-rep doesn't mean you're awesome.  You can be awesome and still be low-rep.  Or show them that I am high-rep and not lazy :P

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113565#8113565):**  That's down to the community - let them decide - as a mod, we're only corner case exception handlers

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113586#8113586):**  Encouragement.  We have some of this on the DBA site, where a lot of big names in the SQL world participate.  There are also a lot of strong personalities (they  **are** DBAs after all) and they require some management.  Mainly if you let the frustrated user know either verbally or through action that their contributions are appreciated, they stay happy.  Most folks like that are motivated by helping and may need some positive feedback from time to time.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113588#8113588):**  I'd probably scour the First Posts section of the Review tools. There can be some real gems there from low-rep users, which I believe can make up for the blunders of high-rep ones.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113594#8113594):**  There's really not much you can do for these users. At best, we can try to show them other high rep users who are not lazy.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113596#8113596):**  Depends what the laziness in question is! Laziness that bothers people tends to make for bad questions; I might edit them, close them, leave a note if they don't get the hint... it really depends on a lot of things.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113603#8113603):**  We, as moderators cannot affect single people. We need to inspire the community to raise the quality level, that's done by serving an example, answering questions yourself, and being active in chat, where experts lie.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113609#8113609):**  I think most experts have already formed an opinion about Stack Overflow. The ones that like it (Eric Lippert, Jon Skeet etc.) are already participating fully. The ones that don't probably won't come back despite your best efforts to persuade them.

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113615#8113615):**  I don't think it's reasonable for anyone to demand that an unpaid question answerer do more work just because you are.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113619#8113619):**  Hmmmm I would show them that "rep" does not really mean much, and that a low rep user can still answer questions and get great results!

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113670#8113670):**  talk to them. give them a hug.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113681#8113681):**  This can be difficult on a site as big as SO but you cannot solely rely on experts to make the site what it is.  There are many people with low-reps that provide fantastic answers to questions. They can't be ignored either.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113761#8113761):**  that's a tough one and in a way it's a broader problem than the moderator role - there are SE employees who are paid to promote and encourage and evangelise the sites and I hope it's something the community as a whole is addressing too. Being approachable and fair counts a lot in that respect though - everyone from new users to experts notices moderators.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113797#8113797):**  I haven't given that any thought, actually. In my opinion, attracting and retaining good users is a tertiary mod responsibility at best. For now, I would say that I wouldn't do anything different than I would as a non-mod, i.e. leave a comment thanking them for how much they've helped me (if they have) or doing nothing if I don't know them.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115213#8115213):**  Drop by [the tavern on meta](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta). There's always someone there who will listen to your story!

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116722#8116722):**  I think that giving them some praise, or "positive reinforcement" as psychology calls it would spur them on to either expand/correct a "lazy" answer, or to answer it themselves with what they deem to be a better answer. A bit of healthy competition, humor and praise is enough to encourage anyone to participate more :)

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124127#8124127):**  I would encourage those notable experts the same way I would encourage any would-be contributor to the site; We have people all over the place working to make the site better, all the time. Some of us - from 3k voters to 10k queue browsers to mods - who work on the 'negative' end; but we also *need* everyone to work on the positive end, contributing superb content; and we all appreciate it. Everyone.

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: swasheck] [swasheck](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/251174/swasheck) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113876#8113876):* **What is the most useful thing (personally, professionally, technically, or otherwise) you've learned from your time on StackOverflow?**

---

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113901#8113901):**  Patience.

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113903#8113903):**  Never, ever, try to parse HTML with regular expressions.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113908#8113908):**  SQL Server programming anti-patterns.  I learned a lot about what NOT to do early on which helped a lot.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113935#8113935):**  The ability to learn from others' mistakes.

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113937#8113937):**  Unicorns are better than ponies. But seriously, I feel that I've learned that it's important to keep a professionalism on any interaction where you use your real name.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113949#8113949):**  People will help you simply because they want to. They expect pretty much nothing in return, and help you simply because they can.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113965#8113965):**  I've expanded my knowledge on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) on that just under year and a half, more than I have for 10 years. Not only technical knowledge, but virtues like patience, strictness and avoiding troll feeding.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113985#8113985):**  I've learned that if I am really stuck and I can write a good question, I can get some help!  Also that JavaScript is silly.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114010#8114010):**  1. How to get my ideas across in written answers. 2. It's improved my search skills.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114016#8114016):**  How to deal with other people's code. (Hell?)

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114119#8114119):**  SQL Server programming. I started coming to SO as an MS Access developer and I have learned so much from reading and answering it is truly amazing.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114564#8114564):**  Stack Overflow has really taught me to appreciate clear technical communication. I had some appreciation of what makes a good/bad question (and psychic debugging services) having come from a usenet background before, but this has really nailed it home and made me think about how I present my own answers as well.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115873#8115873):**  Markdown! I love it! Can't get enough of it...

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116096#8116096):**  I've never learned any single technical thing on SO that was truly mind-blowing, so I guess it'd have to be something about how awesome programmers are, as horribly generic and saccharine as that sounds. But really, there are a lot of amazing SO users, in terms of how they are at coding and at being human beings, and it's really motivating. Okay, let accusations of pandering commence.

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116878#8116878):**  That no matter how right you think you are, there is usually always someone that will provide a much better solution. That's part of the beauty of the community, learning while helping! Not only am I doing the OP a favour, I'm also benefiting by expanding my knowledgebase

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124379#8124379):**  Perhaps I have not learned this so much as had it reinforced, but I would definitely say that Stack Overflow shows that being *precise* about things is important. We're all supposed to be technically-minded people; askers and answerers, alike. We can't be expected to know every fact, but we should all know we get better results when we carefully explain what is important to an issue.

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: Brad Larson] [Brad Larson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114252#8114252):* **If there is a high-reputation subject matter expert who has a history of leaving rude and abusive comments, how do you deal with them when they are flagged for this?**

---

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114274#8114274):**  Tell said expert to stop doing that, politely, and fix things up.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114276#8114276):**  It shouldn't matter who you are.  If you are rude, you will be dealt with.  It'd be a shame to lose someone like John Skeet (if he were rude, which he isn't), but oh well :P

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114285#8114285):**  You handle it just like any other flag. If they are being rude and offensive, delete them, and let the 'expert' know that they are doing something wrong.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114286#8114286):**  I would handle it in the same way I would do with other users. Being a high reputation user is not an excuse to be rude.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114295#8114295):**  If it were a first offence, a simple warning would suffice (after deleting the comments in question, of course). But at the end of the day they could be Stephen friggin' Hawking for all it matters when it comes to being abusive ;)

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114296#8114296):**  For a high reputation user? Contact him privately. Either superping him to chat, or even go as far as a mod message. When a high reputation user is "abusive", that's the message taught to the "younger" folks *"Oh, this guy has 50k, what he's doing is right for sure!"*

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114311#8114311):**  Hmmmm good question.... I would leave a comment responding to the user the reasoning for why his comments were deleted. And if it persists I would have a meeting of the mods to discuss it and maybe send him a mod message.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114312#8114312):**  Their reputation is irrelevant. If they are abusing the system, or hurting other users on the community, they need to be treated as such. I will personally take any such problem user to a private chat, request them to stop. Repeat offenses == timed suspension.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114328#8114328):**  Private chat most likely, then a mod message.  Let them know their contributions are appreciated but the less constructive stuff is not.  Nobody is so important to the site that destructive behavior needs to be tolerated.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114347#8114347):**  Politely letting them though which behaviors are undesirable for the site and asking them to stop, as with any other user. Reputation and status is not an excuse for rudeness.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114382#8114382):**  In the first instance a "be nice" comment or a message in chat would be often enough. If that fails or the situation is larger than one or two comments a warning mod message. If that doesn't help or the user is being particularly rude then a day's suspension is probably called for. It all depends on how bad the situation is. There's no single approach that will work for all.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114440#8114440):**  It should not matter if you are a high or low rep user. But for a high-rep user I would use a private chat to discuss the matter with them.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114501#8114501):**  talk to them. explain the issues. try to find a solution.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114583#8114583):**  No differently than any other user. Start out with warnings in comments, maybe deleting offensive material where necessary, then elevate as needed to stronger warnings, suspensions... checking of course to see what prior action has been taken and what prior experiences other mods have had with the user. It's a great feature of SO that we have so many experts that we don't have to pander to one or two arrogant power users.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114805#8114805):**  Check with the other moderators on this in private chat - I have relatively little inclination what the "normal" response is, in particular how it escalates. Doing nothing is bad. Doing too much is bad. The balance is a fine one and there are people who've been walking that line for a long time.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116062#8116062):**  The comments should be removed and the user reminded of appropriate etiquette (either in an additional comment or a PM if this is a repeat offence)

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8117008#8117008):**  Send him a polite mod message, get him to engage, maybe talk out his angst, there could be other issues behind it. Just be someone to listen, try and re-draw the positives and his love for the community that spurred him on to get a high reputation in the first place.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124654#8124654):**  I think that a high-reputation, subject matter expert who behaves in a bad way can be a significant drag on the site. Flags for them must be handled no differently than for anyone else, but it is perhaps more important to exercise some potential 'external' means to try to impress upon them the importance of being civil, due to their high profile.

Answer (score 2):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/274402/grace-note) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115071#8115071):* As we approach the close of our hour, **final thoughts from the candidates**?

---

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115115#8115115):**  VOTE FOR ME PLEASE! Kidding, vote for whoever you think is the best fit. But preferably me. :p

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115122#8115122):**  Good luck everyone! I am sure whomever wins will be a great moderator!

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115131#8115131):**  Good luck to everyone!

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115133#8115133):**  Thank you for the cookies, the good time, and the questions. I would have preferred bread and salami, but I have still to get that. `:)`

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115134#8115134):**  I think I did my thing here. I'm probably not going to get elected this time, but I have learned a lot, and will improve towards the next election. I'd like to wish good luck for @Gordon, I think he'll make one hell of a mod here.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115139#8115139):**  I hope that I didn't say anything stupid here.  I'd love to be a moderator.  I feel I would be fair, and I would talk to users before closing questions and banning people.  I love to edit posts to fix grammar.  So, please vote for me :)

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115150#8115150):**  Yeah, good luck everyone.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115269#8115269):** Before I forget: as a mod, I'd make everyday a Caturday and we would listen to Rebecca Black on each Friday (we already do so in the PHP chat room)

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115154#8115154):**  A vote for me is a vote for even more close votes.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115159#8115159):**  I can't think of anything I'd like to add. People can see what sort of moderator I'll be from my activity on the other sites.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115160#8115160):**  Whatever happens in the end, this experience has been well worth it, and I am very satisfied with how things have gone so far.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115172#8115172):**  I think good judgement and an even temperament are the most important aspects for a moderator, and I have those.  You have to look beyond the surface frequently.  For instance, very few people noticed the account that Shog9 linked too only posts self-promotional answers.  **Editing the answer is not a solution there, the account is a problem and needs to be dealt with.**

- **[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [remarked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115246#8115246):**  I stand humbly corrected and will take this into account for future cases that come my way.

  **[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115256#8115256):**  Live and learn!

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115231#8115231):**  I think I have the level of patience and judgment that is needed to be a mod on this site.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115406#8115406):**  There's a great selection of candidates here. My suggestion would be to vote based on what you've seen people do, actions speak louder than words. That's how I've picked who I'm going to vote for. I hope you agree with my actions and trust me to be fair and open.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115437#8115437):**  I encourage you to check out my activity history ([comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus?tab=activity&sort=comments), [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus?tab=activity&sort=revisions), [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus?tab=activity&sort=reviews)) as well as the other candidates' histories. If you think of any other questions you'd like to ask me, feel free!

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/505?m=8115448#8115448):** Leave comments under [my nomination blurb](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4#post-15192142) or find me in the [election](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24975/2013-stack-overflow-moderator-election) or [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) chatrooms (in The Tavern, my name is "Popular Demand").

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8117178#8117178):**  Whilst I'd say vote for me, I say vote for whoever you think will be the best for the community. As, after all, that's what we're all here for! :)

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8125096#8125096):**  My final thoughts (though I see other questions coming!) are that I hope people can look beyond the simple fact of my flagging counts, and also see a *tiny bit* of what my hopes are for the site; to keep it of the highest-quality possible, so that it continues to be as helpful for people as it has been to me.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Anna Lear] [Anna Lear](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/105971/anna-lear) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113231#8113231):* **If your answer was that moderators are exception handlers or used a metaphor, can you elaborate on what situations you think are exceptional?**

---

- **[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [asked for clarification](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113245#8113245):**  Can you explain that a little more?

  **[image: Anna Lear] [Anna Lear](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/105971/anna-lear) [clarified](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113254#8113254):**  "Moderators can be anywhere from glorified garbagemen to principals of the school." - What does that mean? Specifically. What does being a garbageman mean for Stack Overflow?

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113246#8113246):**  Exceptional cases are cases that the community alone cannot handle. Abuse, spam, sockpuppeting, and cases which require immediate attention.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113247#8113247):**  Users who regularly cause trouble by posting offensive content, harassing other users, attempting to mess with the rep system by using multiple accounts, &c.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113252#8113252):**  Users abusing the system, picking fights with/insulting other users, spamming, sock puppet accounts, attempts to game the system. Other cases like bad questions, or off topic questions are easily and well handled by the community

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113259#8113259):**  Each situation should be handled individually, abuse is different than just posts that aren't very good.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113261#8113261):**  There are many exceptional situations, such as blocking sock puppets.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113262#8113262):**  There are things that the community just cannot maintain including spam, sockpuppets. There are cases when a moderator is needed.

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113264#8113264):**  One interesting place where moderators may be needed which isn't focused on right now is tag synonyms & maintenance there.  I think that that should be focused on more as a whole.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113265#8113265):**  Exceptions would be rude comments, spam users that need to be nuked, questions on the wrong site (without a votable migration path), comments posted as answers...

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113270#8113270):**  There's always stuff that needs deleting and otherwise cleaning up more quickly than even a large community like Stack Overflow can handle. We need to be there to warn users about potentially disruptive behaviour etc - something that the regular community can't do.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113271#8113271):**  It means cleaning up what might have gone wrong, spam and disruptive users who might not be what is wanted on the network per se.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113511#8113511):**  When submitting a custom flag, it's not a good idea to make the "complaint" public (>10K) - someone needs to be there to review these cases.  Also when a message needs to be sent to a user; perhaps a warning or suspension notice. Here again, it has to be coming from one source - I imagine that suspension notices wouldn't be very clear/consistent/constructive if they were community wikis :)

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116433#8116433):**  Exceptional circumstances I would say are when there's an element of investigative work, or when thinks aren't "black or white". Such situations could go against the majority of participants in said situation, but the Moderator must have the community's interests at heart and not be swayed by personal or social agendas.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8123864#8123864):**  I think I roughly covered this one, but one of my prime items to tackle with my 10k tools and flagging ability is spam and 'Not an Answer' posts; Down-voting these posts as answers is what is generally available to the community, but that does not completely remove them. Downvoting and voting to close (then eventually delete) is what the community could otherwise do to spam questions, but that can take a significant amount of time. These are good examples of items for Moderators.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/274402/grace-note) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113258#8113258):* **What do you consider the most important job of a moderator, amongst all their duties?**

---

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113263#8113263):**  Keeping up with the flag queue.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113267#8113267):**  Maintaining the integrity of the Site.

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113272#8113272):**  The most important part? It has to be the flagging. That's what they're there for, right?

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113274#8113274):**  Calming things down, first and foremost — not that it’s too terribly common to need to do that.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113276#8113276):**  To filter out abuse and keep this place friendly.  That or to help new users understand how to use this place.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113277#8113277):**  Keeping the users happy :-)

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113278#8113278):** Get my flag review queue down to nothing - it bugs me having it on the screen

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113282#8113282):**  The primary function of the site is Q&A - the single most important thing is making that work for the whole community. Without users and content the site would be dead.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113284#8113284):**  I'd say that would be guiding the community, its users (specifically its newer users), so that they learn to be productive and mini-moderators on their own.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113285#8113285):**  It is too keep the level of tolerability to the right degree.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113286#8113286):**  Being the link between the community and Stack Exchange.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113288#8113288):**  Keeping on top of flags. There are a lot of them, and they need to be cleared as often as possible to maintain the quality of the site and boost the signal:noise ratio.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113289#8113289):**  Again this depends on the site.  On DBA we do community building and try to increase awareness/involvement.  On SO you have big city problems, so I think the biggest responsibility on SO would be taking care of broken windows.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113291#8113291):**  Leading the community through your behavior.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113293#8113293):**  Cleaning out low quality stuff and handling flags.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113312#8113312):**  Similar to my answer to the first question, but: dealing with any sort of problem that can't be handled by others. That is, it's more important for mods to deal with suspensions than editing for grammar (and I say that as someone who loves editing).

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113318#8113318):**  good point I can already vote close/delete... but for instance, I'd still rather have the option to bind delete and get rid of unncessary Q's and answers

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113659#8113659):**  In the big picture to spread the ideology of the site... The most obvious way to do this is lead by example. I think beyond the *actions* of a moderator, the most important thing is to be able to communicate the ramifications and rational behind their actions.

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116507#8116507):**  The most important job of a moderator I would say is to do the right thing for the community, however unpopular that decision may be, your main focus must always be the community.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8123893#8123893):**  I definitely think the most important job of a moderator is to do those things that only moderators can do. That really boils down to one thing: handle the moderator queue. As someone who *puts* a lot of things in there now, I think that is extremely important. Pretty much everything else a moderator should do - the community can also do.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Shog9] [Shog9](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113279#8113279):* **If you made it this far, you're *already* moderating Stack Overflow - what do you look forward to doing differently as an elected moderator?**

---

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113292#8113292):**  Being able to take matters into my own hands.  Sometimes I feel I can fix a post myself, and being able to do so would help.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113296#8113296):**  Getting things done faster, for the most part.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113297#8113297):**  Being able to do certain things more quickly - especially on Meta (assuming that the meta diamond comes along with the Stack Overflow one)

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113298#8113298):**  I think that moderators need to do more about the tags on the site. There way too many bad ones that slip through the cracks, and while we have many users dedicated to retagging, it simply isn't enough. As a moderator, I wouldn't have to get the required score in a tag to add a synonym, speeding up the burnination process.

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113299#8113299):**  My biggest frustration as a 20K user is seeing 49K in the close votes queue and having used up my pitiful 50 votes on the front page before noon.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113305#8113305):**  Well for one thing, I *might* not be answering as many questions -- I will try to go through all of what is on my plate (flags and the like) and try to get others to help me in my endevours

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113307#8113307):**  At the moment, my biggest complaint is that there's a limit to how much I can do everyday. I've run out of mod flags and close votes many, many times. The tag which I mainly work on needs a major cleanup. Mod powers will enable me to do more not only on the Android tag, but on the entire site. Also, helping with site maintenance tasks like tag cleanups, burninations etc.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113308#8113308):**  Having the ability to migrate questions would allow me to better deal with the "Off-topic" close votes, so they can be moved to their relevant site and get a better answer there.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113309#8113309):**  I look forward to having more tools available to combat problems and more autonomy to handle things without simply passing the buck to someone else.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113311#8113311):**  Good question, I want to take on the role of a leader, people listen to you more when you got the diamond. I want to educate users to be patient and gracious about newcomers, even when they asked the silliest of questions.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113313#8113313):**  There are many things I cannot do without to be moderator; once of my aims would be to coordinate between the Drupal community on *Stack Overflow*, and *Drupal Answers*.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113317#8113317):**  Having the ability to remove answers without the two-step process of flagging first. Getting things done much faster as a mod.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113329#8113329):**  I think being able to handle issues faster (single vote power) is key on SO since the flood of questions - and related problems - rarely slows down.  Closing/deleting/migrating more efficiently and without waiting for a consensus.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113332#8113332):**  I am looking forward to be part of the moderator team, coordinating my efforts with them.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113996#8113996):**  Binding close votes... no doubt. *(bangs his gavel)*

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116531#8116531):**  Differently, I want to be the one that can act on situations, not just raise them for other people's attention. Whenever I flag it, I feel like I'm passing it off to somebody else. I'd love to be the one who was actually dealing with these matters.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8123918#8123918):**  My goal in becoming a moderator might be obvious, since I already put it in my nomination message: To stop giving the mods more work via my flags, but instead to handle them. Related to that, of course, is to directly handle those things I come across organically as I browse.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/274402/grace-note) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113335#8113335):* **What times of day do you foresee yourself being active as a moderator, which days of the week?**

---

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113355#8113355):**  All of them, why not?

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113356#8113356):**  Every single day, on Indian timings, where we are very short of moderation.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113358#8113358):**  Probably Mon-Fri 9-5 (while I'm at work)

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113362#8113362):**  I see myself active during the 9-5 EST weekday and whenever else I can be in front of a computer.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113363#8113363):**  I think to be active in late evening Italian time (GMT+1, for now).

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113369#8113369):**  Monday - Saturday, and from 10 AM EST - 10 PM EST.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113370#8113370):**  Every day, for sure. One of the first things I do when I wake up is check SO. One of the last things I do before going to bed is check SO!

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113376#8113376):**  I am typically online anywhere from 2am Arizona time until 7pm, so pretty much all day.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113397#8113397):**  8-5pm eastern M-F, off and on on the weekends

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113408#8113408):**  9-5 UTC (give or take 1/2 an hour) though not continually(!) and again 10-12 UTC approx

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113421#8113421):**  Every day from 6:00-8:00, 11:25-12:18, 15:30-19:00 with the occasional important thing overriding from 6:00-23:00.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113435#8113435):**  Except on weekends, where my availability is literally 6:00-21:00.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113438#8113438):**  My schedule changes quite randomly. I can say, though, that I am rarely ever awake between 4am and 8am CST. ;)

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113476#8113476):**  Typically ~1hr in the morning, 1 in the evening on weekdays. Similar total time on weekends.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113497#8113497):**  all days of the week, of course :)

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113501#8113501):**  A little bit during business hours and a bit more during evenings and weekends for eastern-central US time. I don't intend to set aside an "SO moderation hour" or anything; I'll pop in frequently for short periods of time between other activities.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114579#8114579):**  With close to 500 days consecutive visits to the site, I'm pretty sure that's every day of the week... With regard to timezone, I'm in GMT+2 (Israel).

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116592#8116592):**  Predominantly weekdays, pretty much in and out from 8am-7pm GMT. Less frequent on the weekend, I'd probably say a 2-3 hours on Sat and the same on Sun (if not slightly more).

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8123958#8123958):**  My primary activity is likely to be, coincidentally, similar to right now; very early morning US Eastern Time, primarily on business days, and then sporadically throughout the day, 7 days a week.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: swasheck] [swasheck](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/251174/swasheck) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113366#8113366):* **What was your initial reaction to the "Summer of Love?" How do you think it went?"**

---

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113387#8113387):**  It went fine, as far as I can see.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113393#8113393):**  I liked it at the start, it **was** a great idea! but I do not think it was executed fully

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113404#8113404):**  Great idea, not fully executed.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113406#8113406):**  I thought it was a good idea unevenly executed.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113440#8113440):**  I thought the *summer of love* was a great idea. I think that it worked for a time but people have gone back to some snarky behavior.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113448#8113448):**  I was a bit surprised as I didn't initially see the problem. When it was pointed out I could see that there was certainly the impression of prickliness (shall we say). I think it was a good reminder that one of the main rules on Stack Overflow is "be nice".

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113462#8113462):**  The summer of Love was a great campaign, but its worn off a lot of the users now.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113482#8113482):**  To clarify a little bit, I think it is good to encourage being nicer to new users.  However on SO a lack of new users is not an issue - it's cleaning up the trash an keeping signal to noise ratio high.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113517#8113517):**  I was born only in 1976 so I didnt participate in the Summer of Love ;)

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113548#8113548):**  My initial reaction was that it was an odd choice of branding. I think it raised an important point, I think to some extent the message got lost and lots of people seemed to try and use it as an argument not to close/downvote anything ever. Improving the user experience doesn't mean letting any low quality post go.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113561#8113561):**  I thought it was a nice idea, although for the most part it seemed like so many good ideas around here: the people who it was aimed at didn't know about it (or didn't care) and the ones who did know about it didn't really need to be told.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114661#8114661):**  I think it's fantastic that such a notion would be made "official policy", even for a certain period of time. I think overall it went well; I don't think it was meant to totally change the vibe on the site overnight. It drew attention to an important ongoing issue on the site.

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116624#8116624):**  I think what was a fantastic idea could have been executed a little more thoroughly. Although I do appreciate it's a community-wide effort which makes execution incredibly more difficult!

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8123997#8123997):**  My reaction was absolutely positive to the Summer of Love as an idea, and certainly how it made me think twice before responding to things. I know that I've seen others who seem to have tried to 'moderate' themselves. Sometimes it can become a little frustrating responding to something for the umpteenth time, but we have to remember it's not the umpteenth time for *all* of those we're responding to. I don't know if the S.O.L. reached 'everyone', though.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113806#8113806):* **What would you do when a question is flagged for closing, but you aren't an expert on that topic (i.e. tag)?**

---

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113840#8113840):**  It depends on what the flag was for.  If it's a dupe it's a dupe it's a dupe whether you know the subject matter or not.  Same for off-topic.  NARQ may be hard to judge though.  It's impossible to make an honest general assessment on something so broad.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113841#8113841):**  I would try to let the moderators who **know** that tag deal with the closing unless it is a really obvious reason for closure (as in duplicate or not a question)

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113848#8113848):**  It depends on what it's closed for. If it's off-topic or NARQ, generally I can determine if it's valid or not. If it's "not constructive" or "too localized", then I won't do anything at all.

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113853#8113853):**  The vast majority of close votes stand on their own and don't require intimate knowledge of the subject matter. If I honestly have no idea if something's a real question because it's over my head, I'd leave it for someone else to deal with

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113856#8113856):**  I've been programming for several years now. Deep subject knowledge is rarely required to judge whether or not a question can be answered within the scope of StackOverflow. If I am unsure on that question, I will take it to mod chat and ask for a second opinion.

- **[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113879#8113879):**  That's a great stance to have - but what if someone brings up something completely contrary to everything you know, and you honestly can't understand the content of the post? What is your action in that situation?

  **[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113905#8113905):**  Take it for a second opinion. You shouldn't act without being sure.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113862#8113862):**  I've often found that I don't need to know anything about the tag to recognise a bad question. Usually it's the quality of the content that tells the story, not the material contained, if that makes sense. I suck at explaining! But in edge cases, I've found myself hitting the Skip button on occasion. If I were a mod, however, I would bring it up with another mod who might know more.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113883#8113883):**  It depends what kind of close reason, but I usually leave duplicates out of my area well enough alone.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113911#8113911):**  It would largely depend what close votes it had, but most of the time you don't have to be a topic expert to recognise a bad question. If I'm really not sure - just leave it for someone else to deal with. There are other moderators who might well be tag experts and eventually enough tag experts among the community will see the question and vote if necessary.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113923#8113923):**  Depends.  Does the tag have anything to do with the flag?  If so, ask on meta for what to do with it (or can I message other mods to ask for help?)

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113938#8113938):**  Not being expert in a tag doesn't mean not to know when a question should be closed. Moderating doesn't require expertise, and flags that require expertise should be declined. (That is, generally speaking.)

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114041#8114041):**  A mod is not limited to working in the tags they are comfortable in so you would have to make a decision based on what the flag or closing reason is.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114114#8114114):**  defer the decision. ask someone.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114207#8114207):**  Depends. If it's flagged for closing because the user posted "I need a program to do X in [unfamiliar language] in two hours," I'm fine taking it out. If it's flagged for closing because of some language-specific reason, I'll defer to the community or a mod who does know the language/technology in question.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114486#8114486):**  generally flags shouldn't be raising issues that need expert technical knowledge. The checklist of "what makes a good question" can usually be applied with only a very basic knowledge of the subject area. I never close a question because of purely technical knowledge. (The one exception to this is "exact duplicate" closes)

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115843#8115843):**  That all depends on what type of flag was raised. Obviously spam and custom flags shouldn't necessarily be related to technical issues but for off-topic flags, I don't think you have to be an expert to recognize a problematic post.

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116859#8116859):**  If I can't ascertain whether or not that the question is eligible for closing and I'm not comfortable on that topic, I'd leave it for another moderator who is more skilled in that topic enough to make an educated decision.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124355#8124355):**  Quite often, questions flagged/voted for closing do not require domain knowledge. But they *sometimes definitely do*. The greatest type of flag/vote where this seems likely to occur is in 'Exact Dupes', and I am already shy about voting 'Close as Dupe' for those. If I don't know - and this applies to *any* flag - I leave it alone.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114149#8114149):* **How important is it that a candidate has unlocked all privileges, e.g. 20k?**

---

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114161#8114161):**  10K is important, 20K not really.

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114162#8114162):** not at all

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114174#8114174):**  Sort of! Delete-voting and seeing what's been deleted is relevant, so more 10k.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114175#8114175):**  I feel a candidate should have at least got to 10k, though as @AnnaLear has shown us, it is not a hard and fast requirement to be a high rep user to be a good moderator.

- **[image: Anna Lear] [Anna Lear](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/105971/anna-lear) [remarked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114188#8114188):**  Flattery. Good move. ;)

  **[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114215#8114215):**  Shh. Don't reveal my tricks to everyone ;)

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114176#8114176):**  Quite important to me. If they don't have the 20k on at least one site, then it shows me that they don't have the experience that I would like in a candidate.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114184#8114184):**  Not very, as long as they know how to handle the tools and can learn.  None of this stuff is rocket science, but it takes good judgement.  It's not hard to use a hack saw, but it's easy to screw something up seriously if you use it in the wrong spot.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114196#8114196):**  Well ever since I have passed the 10K mark I have learned that Stack Overflow is not as clean as I once thought it was. It taks **a lot** of scrubbing to get it how it is now, and with 4 new moderators hopefully it will only get better :-D

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114197#8114197):**  10K is more important than 20K. I honestly have a hard time seeing someone without the delete priv going on moderatorship. And yes, I know @AnnaLear didn't have it. Still, I've learned much since my 10k.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114204#8114204):**  Fully agree with @Wooble. A good amount of Rep is ideal, but there's more besides that - otherwise they wouldn't be listed on the nominations!

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114213#8114213):**  It's not important. What's more important is their temperament etc.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114219#8114219):**  They should be familiar with the tools we use before being handed them by the community.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114239#8114239):**  it is not that relevant; apart that, there are users who are not 10K users on Stack Overflow, and 20K users on some other sites. Being 20K, or 10K is not so important, as most of the moderation tools are not that hard to use.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114254#8114254):**  I believe 10k is an important mark to hit so that the user can be more familiar with the deletion process. Past that I don't see the other privileges as being too vitally important for a user to have achieved.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114386#8114386):**  I don't think it is very important. If they have access to the 10k tools they have a lot of privileges on the site.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114498#8114498):**  I think it's important that candidates have at least seen the 10k tools on some site (not necessarily SO itself) just so they know what the 10k tools panel looks like and how it works. The higher privileges (15k and 20k) are nice, but not critical.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116005#8116005):**  Not at all. Even the 10K tools take all of 15 minutes to figure out. Reputation and by extension, privileges are irrelevant to moderator potential.

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116966#8116966):**  As long as a candidate has had access to the moderator tools and has had a feel for them, then I say they're ready. I for one am only at 11k, but I feel that when I hit 20k I won't magically become a better mod :)

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124583#8124583):**  I think it is definitely helpful to a candidate to have unlocked the 10k tools; I, for example, would not have the experience I do with flags if I did not have access to the "New Answers to Old Questions" list, which accounts for probably 99% of my flags and 80% of my votes-to-close. I don't think it's *required*, but it's more difficult for someone with less reputation to have been active enough to have enough of a record to consider.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: rlemon] [rlemon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/829835/rlemon) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114385#8114385):* **If elected, what is your stance on interweaving more Unicorns into the Chat/Mainsite UI?**

---

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114396#8114396):**  They need to be everywhere. In the alt texts, in the logo, in the voting icons. Everywhere. UNICORNS FOREVA!

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114398#8114398):**  I'd prefer jabberwocks.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114414#8114414):**  You might want to bold that. As for my answer, I'll work them in subtly ;)

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114435#8114435):**  I am all for it.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114442#8114442):**  MOAR UNICORNS!

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114461#8114461):**  Possibly nice as an Easter Egg at certain times of the year, but otherwise pointless.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114464#8114464):**  Ewno

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114478#8114478):**  I want them free, not closed in a chat room.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114491#8114491):**  no unicorns, it must be smurfs

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114507#8114507):**  Seing as I am a unicorn.  I think the background should be changed to one :)  And every avatar should get a horn!

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114550#8114550):**  I prefer ponycorns. they are cuter

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114624#8114624):**  Assuming this is a serious question: unicorns are a fun meme for SO addicts and Meta-heads to joke about in chat, but that's about it. It's a professional site, after all.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114916#8114916):**  interweaving like horses and burgers?

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116094#8116094):**  As long as there is an opt-out button (for the haters), I'm not against some sparkle. Just not clippycorn ;)

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8117029#8117029):**  I have a Unicorn integration master plan. My mod nomination is simply phase 1 of Unicorn domination. huzzah!

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124746#8124746):**  Unicorns are the glue that holds us all together. I hope I have not offended anyone with visions of unicorns being sent to glue factories. I would never do such a thing. Unless the unicorn was old and weak. I feel like I am digging myself a hole here, so I am going to stop, before I also say that improperly-colored unicorns should probably also be made into some of the glue that holds this place together...

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: swasheck] [swasheck](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/251174/swasheck) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114403#8114403):* **If *not* elected to be moderator, how do you envision your participation to change (if at all)?**

---

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114413#8114413):**  Not at all.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114417#8114417):**  I do not think my participation would change at all.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114418#8114418):**  I don't see it changing at all.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114421#8114421):**  It won't.  Well, I may try to use my /review and /tools a bit more, but otherwise the same :)

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114432#8114432):**  No change (either way, by the way).

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114433#8114433):**  It would continue as it is today, and I would very likely run again.  I don't think anyone in this group will ragequit if not elected.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114436#8114436):**  If not elected moderator, I continue participating as I have been, potentially even more if I can, and then try again next time.

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114438#8114438):**  I'll prepare to go for the next round. Improve my flag counts & meta participation.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114439#8114439):**  I don't think it will change at all. It would eventually change what I can do to help moderate the site; that's all.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114456#8114456):**  Not at all. I'm used to disappointment by now ;)

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114457#8114457):**  Work harder and try again next time.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114460#8114460):**  In all honesty I'd probably do a little less moderating for a few days, but I'd soon bounce back. It's not the end of the world!

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114547#8114547):**  I will go hide in the corner and cry.  No seriously it would not change my participation in the site. I love this site, it has made me a better developer at work so being a mod or not my participation wouldn't change.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114589#8114589):**  my participation wont be affected.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114666#8114666):**  I don't anticipate any changes. Why should an election loss impact participation?

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114953#8114953):**  I'll probably take a short break and then business as normal.

- **[image: swasheck] [swasheck](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/251174/swasheck) [remarked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114962#8114962):**  thank you for your honesty

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116114#8116114):**  Not at all. When I start preparing my nomination post for the next election my participation might be affected slightly ;)

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8117034#8117034):**  It wouldn't change at all, I'd still go on being equally as passionate and committed to the community.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124764#8124764):**  If I am not elected a moderator, I will promptly go to my bouncy castle and throw a tantrum. Then, I will get back to flagging, voting, and Meta participation. Just like I did after the last two times I was not elected.

Answer (score 1):

### *[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115143#8115143):* **How will you, as a moderator, improve our standing in external communities (such as reddit) where we have a negative reputation?**

---

- **[image: NullUserException] [NullUserException](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115161#8115161):**  we have a negative reputation on reddit?

  **[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115167#8115167):**  A very negative one, yes.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115173#8115173):**  Reddit is not the kind of place we should be seeking reputation anyway. StackOverflow can stand for itself :)

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115179#8115179):**  Our community has nothing to do with reddit.

- **[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [remarked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115198#8115198):**  True, but you represent stackoverflow as a whole. You could make a difference in how we are viewed outside of stackoverflow, and how important is that to you?

  **[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [noted](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115224#8115224):**  We are not representatives of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/).

  **[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115226#8115226):**  I would do my best here to make this a happy place.  Let them think what they want. Haters gonna hate.

  **[image: Anna Lear] [Anna Lear](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/105971/anna-lear) [noted](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115238#8115238) to [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha):**  Not legally, but I think you'll find that most people don't bother making that distinction.

  **[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [clarified](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115251#8115251):** We may be the unofficial representatives from inside the community, but we will not go out and speaking in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)'s name.

  **[image: Jeremy Banks ᐛ] [Jeremy Banks ᐛ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1114/jeremy-banks) [noted](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115258#8115258):** I've seen several existing moderators speak out in Stack Overflow's defence when Reddit or Hacker News was being particularly negative.

  **[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [replied](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115270#8115270):**  of course not. but that doesn't mean that your actions won't be viewed negatively by them, as they are publicly visible.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115193#8115193):**  I don't think the premise of this question is true at all...

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115197#8115197):**  I pledge to upvote every positive comment about SO on reddit on my first day as moderator, because I can totally change the minds of trolls and arguing with people who are wrong on the internet is a great use of time.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115199#8115199):**  … what? I don't care. Stack Overflow users are the only ones in a position to know what's going on anyways.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115200#8115200):**  We don't care, nor should we. We are moderators, not publicity men.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115233#8115233):**  I'm not sure this is really an issue or the job of the moderator team.  SO is a well respected resource already.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115236#8115236):**  Nothing. It is outside our control, and we were elected to moderate the community, not popularize the site.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115268#8115268):**  That is not a moderator's task.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115294#8115294):**  I don't think this is the job of the mod team.  Anyone who participates is a representative of the community.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115310#8115310):**  People who post negative stuff on places like reddit aren't likely to have their minds changed by anything I could say. My "job" is to keep Stack Overflow on course and if that means that some people don't participate then so be it. We can't be all things to all people - that way lies Yahoo! Answers.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115313#8115313):**  I don't use Facebook, Twitter, Reddit, Pinterest, HackerNews or anything else of the sort, so I would be a net zero.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115463#8115463):**  I don't have a reddit account. I saw a /. story today that was pleasantly positive. I hope I'll project a good image into my zone of influence. Reddit isn't the only programmers community out there and SO is highly regarded in many areas precisely because of some of the controversial issues.

- **[image: Mysticial] [Mysticial](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial) [remarked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116058#8116058):**  The one you saw today (and yesterday's as well) were both mostly positive. The really bad ones were from a few weeks back.

  **[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116216#8116216):**  I missed those specific ones. I was aware that there were some negative views though. (I get my tech news from theregister mostly). It's a hard problem though, but most programmers I know in the real world say stuff like "I couldn't live without it" when they mention SO.

  **[image: Mysticial] [Mysticial](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial) [replied](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116270#8116270):**  Here's an example: http://www.reddit.com/r/coding/comments/18evsw/how_to_program_if_youre_blind/c8eegc0

  **[image: Mysticial] [Mysticial](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116283#8116283):** But yes, it's not an easy problem to solve when outsiders don't understand how SO/SE works.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8125123#8125123):**  Our standing in other communities, such as Reddit, is not at all a primary concern of mine. If we run our site how we feel it should be run, that's our business. They are entitled to their opinion too, of course. But that's their business.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Shog9] [Shog9](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113990#8113990):* **How embarrassed are you that, for all the time you've spent supposedly helping to keep the site clean, you've still cast waaaaay fewer close votes than Wooble?**

---

- **[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [asked for clarification](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114003#8114003):**  How many has he cast?

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114023#8114023):**  Very. *runs and hides in the closet*  No, but seriously, I did my best to help.  If someone did better, good for them, but I still helped :)

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114030#8114030):**  Not embarrassed at all. rarely do I vote to close when I can edit something instead. It's not an important statistic to have IMO, as it just shows that you aren't willing to edit valid posts.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114036#8114036):**  That's like asking "How embarrassed are you that, for all the time you've spent supposedly helping answer questions on the site, youe still have waaaaaaay less reputation than Jon Skeet". I don't mind other people's business (until they hurt someone). Wooble's awesome, I can be awesome as well.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114037#8114037):**  Not embarrassed but good for him!  Everyone can do more than they currently do for the site.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114045#8114045):**  Not in the slightest. Each person helps moderate the site in their own way, plus I don't spend all day on the site (despite appearances otherwise).

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114051#8114051):**  I cannot keep casting closing votes; I much prefer to cast less close-votes, and let more users partecipate in that.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114057#8114057):**  Nothing to be embarrassed about. Everyone does their own work on the site. some answer, some edit, some ask, some flag, some close.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114072#8114072):**  I don't care! I edit more ;)

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114082#8114082):**  I can't say that it's embarrassing at all. It's just a number, and I know that I will cast many a close vote more in my time here. We probably just interact with the community in vastly different ways.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114090#8114090):**  If closing votes were my pride and joy, I guess I'd be a little embarrassed, but not really. It's just a number.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114304#8114304):**  I am not embarrassed by it. I spend time flagging, editing and answering questions as well.  We all perform different tasks when we are on the site.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114373#8114373):**  Just a little. I once read a quotation about how everyone takes different paths in life, and just because two people are on different paths doesn't make either of them more good or bad, more right or wrong. Close votes are an important cleanup task on SO, but they're just one way to help out. So I say good for Wooble! But I'm not going to hang my head in shame over my relative lack of close votes, either.

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116919#8116919):**  Well done to Wobble I say :). We're all working for a common goal, keeping the community as relevant and as clean as we can, so one can only applaud Wobble's voting record.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124466#8124466):**  I definitely respect anyone who, as a moderator candidate, has shown that my massive 'Helpful Flag' count is not a be-all, end-all. There are other important metrics that I feel should be shared, such as close votes. We each concentrate in different areas, and I'm very glad to be among candidates who have differing - and superior - abilities and focus than mine.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: swasheck] [swasheck](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/251174/swasheck) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114074#8114074):* **In matters of moderation, what do you believe would be your "go-to" tool?**

---

- **[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [asked for clarification](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114118#8114118):**  I am not sure what you mean.... Flags, editing, commenting, making balloon animals?

  **[image: swasheck] [swasheck](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/251174/swasheck) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114154#8114154):**  Yes?

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114094#8114094):**  `/questions`.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114095#8114095):**  I don't understand the question.

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114097#8114097):**  FALCON PUNCH! No, not really. I think that 'edit' is probably the most important one.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114117#8114117):**  Depends on the matter at hand. Not all matters can be handled with a single tool.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114124#8114124):**  My keyboard, OF DOOM!  That and the "add comment" link.  Explaining to people how to fix their post before I close it.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114129#8114129):**  `/tools`, hands down.

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114132#8114132):** I don't have any specific tool, just pen and paper and some common sense

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114140#8114140):**  The flag queue and my disarming personality.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114152#8114152):**  I'm not sure if there is any "go-to" tool.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114157#8114157):**  Definitely the edit. It has a lot of power, for good or bad.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114172#8114172):**  I use all the tools moderators have; I don't have a preferred one.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114288#8114288):**  Moderators are more reactive and proactive  - especially on a larger site - so the tools you use will depend on the flags being raised etc. I certainly don't go looking for stuff to moderate so I don't have a need to have a tool to help me find stuff to do.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114324#8114324):**  mod tools

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114415#8114415):**  common sense (no, not the user formerly known as col shrapnel)

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114420#8114420):**  I don't think it's wise to answer this without prior mod tool experience. If anyone decides to not vote for me because I don't already have a diamond on another site, that's his prerogative and I'm okay with that.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114759#8114759):**  Not 100% sure I've understood this question correctly - in terms of knowledge ("what's the precedent here?") chat has to be the most useful thing. I expect I'll largely be working with the flag queue.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115976#8115976):**  Any link to the users summary page

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116938#8116938):**  My passion and dedication, that'll get me through everything :)

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124519#8124519):**  My 'go-to' tool for matters of moderation (speaking here of handling flags) would be my more experienced, fellow moderators. I have already learned a bit from them there (though @BradLarson has had to remind me of some things more than once re my most frequent reason for declined Spam flags), and I expect that to continue.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/274402/grace-note) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114584#8114584):* **Do you have a major interest or hobby outside of the world of computer tech?**

---

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114592#8114592):**  Nomic, NetHack, ice hockey.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114599#8114599):**  I play the Pokémon Trading Card Game somewhat seriously and I'm a major collector. Other than that, not really.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114601#8114601):**  Does being obsessed with MLP:FiM count?

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114603#8114603):**  Not particularly. I did play football for [7 years](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgJI-YrJ_8o), but those days are behind me.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114605#8114605):**  Photography and reading.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114606#8114606):**  Ummmm. walking, biking. being corny. being married. oldest of 6. LOVE DOCTOR WHO! ummm thats about it.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114608#8114608):**  Raising my kids.  I'm also getting active in some social causes after a tragedy in my hometown.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114610#8114610):**  I exercise too much, mainly running. If I am not doing that I remodel my house or play video games.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114613#8114613):**  Reading, writing, tennis.

- **[image: NullUserException] [NullUserException](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114642#8114642):**  Who is the GOAT in Tennis, in your opinion?

  **[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [asked for clarification](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114671#8114671):**  Is that a tennis thing? I just play tennis.

  **[image: NullUserException] [NullUserException](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) [clarified](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114681#8114681):**  Greatest Of All Time

  **[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114700#8114700):**  You are. Obviously.

  **[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114745#8114745):**  I don't know. I play tennis.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114614#8114614):**  Reading, movies (though I don't get to see as many films as I'd like these days) and walking the dog.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114620#8114620):**  diving and trying to be a guitar player. with varying success

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114627#8114627):**  Video games! I own over 300, and that's usually what I'm doing when not browsing around the SE network.

- **[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114633#8114633):**  That's tech related, no?

  **[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114648#8114648):**  Not computer tech. Unless you play on the computer, which I don't.

  **[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [replied](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114658#8114658):**  PC MASTER RACE! I kid. Carry on :)

  **[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/274402/grace-note) [added](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114659#8114659):**  I probably could've been clearer in saying "dev stuffs", since that's more the inclination I was going for.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114628#8114628):**  Not really, most of my hobbies are computer related. Be it programming, or computer gaming. I do love deep philosophical and/or theological arguments.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114645#8114645):**  Yes, I do: learning English, trying to learn Esperanto, and Sci-Fi.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114715#8114715):**  I have other interests, yes. You'll have to define "major" or give me a better idea where you're headed with that question if you want more information than that, though.

- **[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/274402/grace-note) [replied](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114750#8114750):**  Well, rather than necessarily listing all the things you enjoy doing, just think of what you'd consider amongst the top things you truly love.

  **[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114944#8114944):**  So you want me to actually specify one or more hobbies, then?

  **[image: Grace Note] [Grace Note](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/274402/grace-note) [replied](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114959#8114959):**  As much as you are comfortable with.

  **[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115234#8115234):**  Volunteering on an ambulance, playing games (video and board).

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114993#8114993):**  Yes. Boats. Photography. Climbing.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116153#8116153):**  Is this a trick question? ;)

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8117060#8117060):**  You mean there's other hobbies outside computer tech? Jokes :). I like playing/watching football (soccer if you're American), console games, reading about physics (mainly space, quantum etc.).

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124796#8124796):**  I have two major hobby interests beyond this sort of stuff; I play Airsoft (like paintball, but with look-alike replicas of real-life weapons, and 6mm plastic pellets instead of paint), and I am a GM of table-top RP games with a regular group of friends.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114588#8114588):* **Which tags do you believe are in desperate need of maintenance right now and what will you do to help out with said maintenance?**

---

- **[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [asked for clarification](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114660#8114660):**  Tags? As in synonyms, or the questions within?

  **[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [clarified](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114664#8114664):**  Questions within

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114604#8114604):** I want the python tag cleaned up - [sopython.com](http://sopython.com/)

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114623#8114623):** and then seeing i put work into it, I want it more available to others

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114607#8114607):**  [php](/questions/tagged/php), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), [android](/questions/tagged/android). All of those need attention. I'm active on two of the three.

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114615#8114615):**  Android, php, and somewhat the C++ tags all could use some help.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114622#8114622):**  [php](/questions/tagged/php), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) <-- ones that I am active in

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114631#8114631):**  I don't believe in giving more attention to specific tags (except the ones that are frequently misused because of misunderstandings, which I tend to adopt as favorites), but looking at questions individually on their own merit.

- **[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [remarked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114656#8114656):**  But some tags have major quality problems. For exame, the Android tag gets a lot of new questions everyday. Many of these are duplicates.

  **[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114703#8114703):**  If people want to vote for someone who the Android community will break legs for because they want their tag cleaned up, they know who to vote for.

  **[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [replied](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114711#8114711):**  Ah. My campaign manager has become famous ;)

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114641#8114641):**  I think the folks in those tags can probably tell us better than we can deduce on our own.  There are millions of users and a few dozen mods - let's crowdsource some of that initial filtering to see what needs attention.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114651#8114651):**  I think all [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) questions should be answered with raw [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) because [Vanilla JS is a lost art](http://vanilla-js.com/) :p In all seriousness, though, it's also one of the most active so is bound to have more to clean up.

- **[image: Amaan Cheval] [Amaan Cheval](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/401137/amaan-cheval) [remarked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114684#8114684):**  I've got pretty much the same reason. You don't need jQuery to do *everything*

  **[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114706#8114706):**  Awesome (#[^_^]#)

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114685#8114685):**  Err... all of them have their bad moments. I don't discriminate :P

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114663#8114663):**  [php](/questions/tagged/php), problem is lots of people just post links and say "fix this".  I'd tell them they need to clean up their question and direct them to similar ones.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114668#8114668):**  I think a lot can be done to clean up the MySQL and PHP tags.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114717#8114717):**  I see poor question in all tags. Those that I know something about I can edit and/or close others I'm going to have to leave to others as I don't have the domain knowledge to improve the answer. All I could do would get bad stuff closed more quickly, but that isn't always the best approach.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114725#8114725):**  I'd say PHP is a mess. Simply because it's the most popular scripting language, is installed on 80% servers and everyone can pick it up so easily. We have tons of dupes in there. It could benefit from a full time mod actually.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114755#8114755):**  I'd help out like I already do. PHP is my main tag and I am part of the cv-ring, e.g. a group of PHP enthusiasts meeting the php chat room and coordinating cleaning there. We even wrote our own tools to assist us with that.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114727#8114727):**  Tags related to Drupal needs some assistance, especially because perfectly answerable questions are closed as off-topic, or not constructive, when they are not.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114744#8114744):**  [android](/questions/tagged/android) and [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) get a lot of complaints. I don't plan to actively go into any tags for cleanup runs, mod-guns blazing, but if there are more flags coming from those areas, I'll probably be spending a proportionate amount of time there.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115064#8115064):**  my intention is to go where the flags take me rather than spending a massive amount of time seeking out problems. There are certainly tags with quality issues. I have a tag blacklist optimised for reading questions I like currently, I'll remove that if elected.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116192#8116192):**  The active tags always need the most attention. A good way to help with mass cleanups it a constructive meta post calling users to action.

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8117086#8117086):**  I don't think I would know which tags are in desperate attention, but if one was raised by a community member, I'd surely divert my attention and help clean it up (voting, editing, deleting, migrating questions etc.).

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124823#8124823):**  One of my major tag-related crusades is watching the newly-created tags for misspellings, and obviously Meta tags (probably because my default 10k Tools view is the one that includes new tags at the bottom). My hope there is to try to prevent new tags from being tomorrow's train wrecks. Beyond that, I look out for current issues on Meta, and edit when I can.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: rlemon] [rlemon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/829835/rlemon) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114644#8114644):* **Scenario Question: If an argument arose between two users (say in the chat) and third parties flagged it unaware or the context, but both parties find the argument constructive; would you ban them? disband the argument? or file them into their own little room (the two arguing that is)**

---

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114701#8114701):**  I would first look for the context, and then make a decision.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114704#8114704):**  They would probably be better off directed into their own room to be constructive with each other without disrupting others.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114719#8114719):**  Read through the logs, that's why they're there. If the argument is obviously interrupting or annoying the other users in the room, I would ask them to move their conversation into a different room.

**[image: animuson] [animuson](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114741#8114741):**  If it's in chat, I can't say that any action is needed on a moderator's part. If users find it annoying that they're arguing there, they can always ask them to move somewhere else on their own. I imagine it would have to be a pretty extreme case to warrant manually moving their conversation for them.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114758#8114758):**  I'd see if I could figure out the context.  If it wasn't useful, I'd remove the comments.  If it was useful, I'd see if I could make a chat room for them.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114778#8114778):**  It depends from the argument, and which tone they keep.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114784#8114784):**  I'd tell them to continue their argument in a way that doesnt attract more flagging

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114785#8114785):**  Show up, let the users know that they've caused a disturbance in the opinion of other users and ask them to tone it down for a minute or two. That'll give me a chance to read the context. After I do that, I can decide whether they need to be censured, censored or suspended.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114794#8114794):**  I would read the transcript to get some context on the situation and if need be ask them to move to a separate room

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115153#8115153):**  flags in chat have historically been pretty tricky. A lot goes in chat that wouldn't be acceptable on the main site. Unless it was pretty serious (doesn't sound like it from your description) I'd probably just stop by and see for a while.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116250#8116250):**  Move it to a different room. Although "constructive" is a pretty broad definition, as long as they are not at each others throats they can just take it to their own room... let them CAPS all they want in there...

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8117112#8117112):**  Not banning no, as the argument is deemed constructive then I would politely encourage them to move the conversation into another room, thus keeping all parties happy.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124856#8124856):**  What to do with two users misbehaving in chat would first depend on the prevailing atmosphere of that chat room. Many flags would strongly suggest it is out of the accepted norm. My first hope would be to *convince* the two to take it somewhere private. If that needs to be done with a firmer hand, so be it.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: rlemon] [rlemon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/829835/rlemon) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114807#8114807):* **As a moderator, will you take the time to "get to know the community" on a personal level?**

---

-**[image: rlemon] [rlemon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/829835/rlemon) [clarified](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114807#8114807):** I often see Mods in the chats and answering / helping with questions/answers - but then there are mods who i've never seen outside of meta or "here when something has happened". It's not that important that you get to know us, i'm just curious to know who will.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114819#8114819):**  I'll buy anyone who upvotes my posts/votes for me a beer! :-D  I'd like to get to know people here, it'd be nice :)

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114832#8114832):**  invisible cookies for all!

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114857#8114857):**  I don't really use the chat much to begin with, but apart from that, yes.

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114858#8114858):**  I think it's important. A moderator isn't there only to solve problems anonymously. He's there to be a figure.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114865#8114865):**  Yes I already do that to an extent. I am in the chat room The Heap on DBA.SE most days mainly due to the direct connection with my job.  This same community is in the tags I am active in.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114868#8114868):**  I like to know who I'm working with. I like to know when people have problems and if there's anything I can do to help, even if it's just "be here so I can rant to you".

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114872#8114872):**  I'm already very active in the Android chat room, and depending on what technologies I use further on, I may join the PHP and JavaScript rooms (and possible C++)

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114883#8114883):**  I already know the community around my tags pretty well, so I'll continue that if elected.

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114886#8114886):**  "The Community" is hundreds of thousands of people. You can't know them all personally.

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114917#8114917):**  I don't frequent chat as much as some users - but I do feel like I will be there to give helpful feedback on subjects that I may have input on, I don't see that changing. most of my activity now is edits & comments, both of which are critical to being a moderator

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114975#8114975):**  I am usually in the PHP chat room. But the community is rather big, so getting to know the community on a personal level is unfortunately largely impossible. I'd love to attend some sort of SO meetup though.

- **[image: rlemon] [rlemon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/829835/rlemon) [remarked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115004#8115004):**  yea this is the answers I expected. I do see mods sticking to their areas of expertise. and I wouldn't for a second expect anyone to get to know everyone. Just wondering the stance on community involvement from a "soon to maybe be" mod.

  **[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [responded](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115044#8115044):**  What is your definition of community involvement?

  **[image: rlemon] [rlemon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/829835/rlemon) [replied](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115072#8115072):**  involvement in the community :P (I know not helpful, but I was tossing the term in loosely)

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115007#8115007):**  To some degree, yes. I already participate in Meta a lot -- I think I'm one of the top five users who isn't a current or former mod? -- and some chats, but my lack of subject matter expertise keeps me out of the comment threads of most questions.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115024#8115024):**  I once attended an SO meetup, it was fun.  We need more of those!

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115062#8115062):**  I much prefer to be active as moderator, and in the meta site. Those are the places where I can help more.

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115063#8115063):**  As I'm on line mainly from work it's difficult (if not impossible) to have multiple chat windows open. I try to get into the various rooms when I can, but in terms of being available to the community it has to be when I'm free.

**[image: Flexo] [Flexo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115311#8115311):**  I think I'm already somewhat known in the community. I hope it'll stay that way.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116350#8116350):**  Sure! I'll go where the action is!

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8117148#8117148):**  I feel that getting to know the community on a personal level is a pretty important step. It helps you further understand the person behind the words, sometimes it's difficult to come across, but if you know someone on a personal level, you'll know exactly what they mean.

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8125016#8125016):**  Chats are, admittedly, one of my weak points. I don't tend to be able to 'hang out' on the site enough to make chatting a frequent thing I can effectively do. I expect I would try to 'pop in' a bit more often, but I have to honestly say that kind of participation would not lend itself to 'getting to know' the chat community all that well.

Answer (score 0):

### *[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114920#8114920):* **How much do you think this Town Hall affected your vision/viewpoint/chances of getting elected?**

---

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114933#8114933):**  I hope I didn't say anything stupid :)  Also, it made me see that I may need to think more about what I'd do as a mod.

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114948#8114948):**  If anything, it has hurt them. That conversation with neal put me at odds with some people, but I didn't come into the election with high hopes.

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114951#8114951):**  I think my chances have stayed the same.

**[image: Kolink] [Kolink](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114961#8114961):**  I have no idea! I hope I've shown people a bit more about who I am, and what I can bring to the table. That said, my vision/viewpoint of *other* candidates has been somewhat altered.

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114967#8114967):**  Hopefully it's helped me.  I know it's clarified who I am/am not voting for among the other candidates.  I hope it gives voters a better idea of how we will operate as mods.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114968#8114968):**  I hope they've gone up, but I really can't say :P

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114978#8114978):**  Possibly because the questions are coming thick and fast I don't think that the actual chat will affect whether people vote for me or not. I think that will come when people read the transcript and meta post.

**[image: Wooble] [Wooble](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114979#8114979):**  I think I'm now the clear frontrunner. Sorry, Andrew, wherever you are.

**[image: bluefeet] [bluefeet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114982#8114982):**  Well I hope that I have been able to state some additional points of view that were not in my nomination.  I hope it has helped my chances.

**[image: minitech] [minitech](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114984#8114984):**  I don't think it changed much. I hope not. Otherwise, I've been explaining myself pretty badly in nominations.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114988#8114988):**  It didn't change anything: Those who up-voted me already voted; those who down-voted me already voted. Nobody is going to change their vote because something I said here.

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115006#8115006):**  The Town Hall meeting has shown that I am the mod everyone is looking for. *makes Jedi gesture*

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115145#8115145):**  This chat has made me think a little more about the aspects of moderation that don't immediately come to mind when you think about day-to-day mod business. By that, I mean evangelizing about SO, retaining good members and figuring out how the site can best serve the community on a large scale (rather than an individual-question scale). But other than that, I don't feel very different.

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [continued](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8115183#8115183):**  I'm *extremely* familiar with Meta, I've read the transcripts of past Town Halls, I read the mod newsletters occasionally, I listen to some of the podcasts... there were no huge shockers in here.

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8117168#8117168):**  I hope it's improved them. I've simply tried to portray my beliefs/passion throughout my answers to the questions and I hope that they're seen as positive :).

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8125056#8125056):**  I don't think my viewpoint/vision, or chances of being elected are significantly effected. I think my views and activity are well-enough established/known and nothing here feels out of expectations, there. My biggest hope is that some who don't know me from Meta will get a better idea about me, knowing whether to vote for me, or not.

Answer (score -1):

### *[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113661#8113661) candidates who are already SE moderators:* **How do you feel being a mod on another site would affect your moderation on Stack Overflow?**

---

**[image: ChrisF] [ChrisF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113717#8113717):**  Well I'll be able to "hit the ground running" as I'm familiar with the tools. I'm around most of the day anyway so having one more site to look after (with the other moderators of course) won't be an problem (hopefully).

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113723#8113723):**  I think it would only strengthen both of my sites. I think being a moderator on both a low-profile and a high-profile site has some very interesting advantages, you get the best of both worlds, you learn to be strict on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), while you learn to be patient and gracious on [Anime and Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/).

**[image: JNK] [JNK](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/397952/jnk) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113724#8113724):**  The effort required for moderating other sites pales in comparison to the demands on SO.  I have some tangential understanding from current SO mods about what is needed.  There are very few flags on my site and we have several other very active mods, so I could focus more on SO without hurting DBA.

**[image: kiamlaluno] [kiamlaluno](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/225647/kiamlaluno) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8113738#8113738):**  It will not affect how I moderate Stack Overflow, since Drupal Answers doesn't require 30 minutes of moderating, if not in very exceptional cases (such as spammers).

Answer (score -4):

### *[image: swasheck] [swasheck](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/251174/swasheck) [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114249#8114249):* **What happens when you kill the joe?**

---

**[image: Richard J. Ross III] [Richard J. Ross III](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114257#8114257):**  He dies?

**[image: Jon Clements] [Jon Clements](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114272#8114272):** bury him under the patio? Hope the police don't find out later?

**[image: Madara Uchiha] [Madara Uchiha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114301#8114301):**  joe dies.

**[image: Rocket Hazmat] [Rocket Hazmat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114323#8114323):**  I think I missed the joke @_@

**[image: Neal] [Neal](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114329#8114329):**  42 things.

**[image: Raghav Sood] [Raghav Sood](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114331#8114331):**  Make sure I use a plastic tub when taking care of the body *breaking bad reference*

**[image: Gordon] [Gordon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114476#8114476):**  I make more coffee

**[image: Lord Torgamus] [Lord Torgamus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8114515#8114515):**  I don't understand this reference, sorry.

**[image: Lix] [Lix](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116034#8116034):**  He dies, @swasheck... He *dies*...

**[image: mattytommo] [mattytommo](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8116980#8116980):**  You make some mo'. As Terry Tate would say ;)

**[image: Andrew Barber] [Andrew Barber](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) [answered](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8124606#8124606):**  I am sorry to say that I completely miss the apparent joke, here. Who is Joe, and why does he deserve to be killed? And, the most important question: is someone flagging it?

Comment: Really, what does this mean?

Comment: @minitech: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RzToNo7A-94