# How to decide on who should be a moderator?

Tags: discussion, flags, election

While voting, I realize that I am choosing who will be in control of the site, and possibly closing all my questions in the near future, So how should the decision be made ?

Personally, I based on those things:

1. the number of helpful flags (because if they know what to flag, they are better on the other side deciding which flags should be deemed helpful, -- and instead of flagging posts for other moderators to review, they should act faster and not flag and wait for a response)
2. their reply to some of the questions in here [February 2013 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat Digest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170715/210465)
3. their text they wrote here https://stackoverflow.com/election/4?tab=election

Comment: Note that much of the control of the site, especially closing questions, is done mainly by regular users with the close question privilege.  Not by moderators.

Comment: Should be closed as "Not a real question. Will give rise to interminable discussion."

Comment: `...and possibly closing all my questions in the near future` - stop asking terrible questions then. Moderators deal with other things as well, if you are focused on who's going to be closing your questions, maybe the answers you seek can be found within... :-P

Comment: If this had a definitive answer, why would we be having elections ?

Comment: Just vote for whomever you like the most.  I'll take over closing all your questions from now on.  ;p

Comment: 2 of the 3 I voted for have won (my 1st and 3rd positions), if this was a guess game, as in `guess who will be a moderator`, I think I won. :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Umm, what exactly is the question?

You have specified what you intend to base your decision on - these are some of the correct ways to gather information - are you needing someone to validate that approach for you? If so then *yes, that is a good place to start*.

I would encourage you to base your decision on their track record, personally I think a vote based purely on popularity is a wasted vote. Read the last paragraph of Shog9's blog post [*VOTE NOW in the 2013 Stack Overflow Moderator Election*](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/03/2013-so-moderator-election/?cb=1). Take note of the last sentence:

> Remember that moderation doesn’t *start* with winning an election.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two rules in an election:

### 1. Vote Early

### 2. Vote Often